# Is there any overhead if i use function as static compared to non-static function

Tags: c, linux, gcc

I know why we use the static function, I bother about if I use a function as a static then any overhead of my application(in term of execution speed and memory)?
Note:- My query about function not for a static variable.

Comment: You're worrying about overhead where you shouldn't.

Comment: @StoryTeller as you suggest I remove C++ and my query about in C  language.please help me out so understand

Comment: @DeiDei yes I am worried about any overhead on my application in term of memory and execution speed.

Comment: Good start. But still unclear and quite broad. There are many types of overhead (space, build time, run time). Asking an unqualified question is not a good way to go. You should also present a use-case where you think it could matter.

Comment: @StoryTeller thanks for your suggestion, as per your suggestion I mention all term

Comment: `static` on a function is a linkage specifier. The speed of the function should be the same as linkage affects visibility. Maybe the answer is, it does not matter. Also see [What does “static” mean in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/572547/608639) and [The static keyword and its various uses in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15235526/608639).

Comment: Why my question downvote? am I ask wrong question or something else?

Answer (score 0):

On many architectures, calls to `static` functions are more efficient than calls to non-static functions.  To address this, SQLite and some other projects have a compilation mode called the [almalgamation](https://www.sqlite.org/amalgamation.html), where almost everything is compiled as a single source file, and internal functions are `static`.

When compiling with optimization, GCC will also automatically inline static functions which are only called once because this is almost always beneficial to do so.