# Declaring and defining function static yields "undefined reference to function_name()"

Tags: c++, g++, linker-errors

Here's the function prototype declaration defined in `utils.hpp` (NON OOP, so not in any class)

```
static void create_xy_table(const k4a_calibration_t *calibration, k4a_image_t xy_table);

static void generate_point_cloud(const k4a_image_t depth_image,
                                 const k4a_image_t xy_table,
                                 k4a_image_t point_cloud,
                                 int *point_count);

static void write_point_cloud(const char *file_name, const k4a_image_t point_cloud, int point_count);
```

And I have their definitions in `utils.cpp` which includes `utils.hpp`.

When I call use any of the function at `main` function in `main.cpp`, I get the following error:

```
/tmp/ccFcMfYB.o: In function `main':
main.cpp:(.text+0x208): undefined reference to 
`create_xy_table(_k4a_calibration_t const*, _k4a_image_t*)
```

Compilation command:

`g++ -o build/testtest src/main.cpp src/utils.cpp -I./include -lk4a`

**Defining all functions as not static and compiling works perfectly!!** I can't wrap my head around this.

- What exactly is happening?
- What should one do to properly include / link if one needs to define and link static functions?

My System Config:
gcc version 7.4.0 (Ubuntu 7.4.0-1ubuntu1~18.04.1)

**EDIT**:
Here's my function definition in utils.cpp:

```
static void create_xy_table(const k4a_calibration_t *calibration, k4a_image_t xy_table)
{
    k4a_float2_t *table_data = (k4a_float2_t *)(void *)k4a_image_get_buffer(xy_table);

    int width = calibration->depth_camera_calibration.resolution_width;
    int height = calibration->depth_camera_calibration.resolution_height;

    k4a_float2_t p;
    k4a_float3_t ray;
    int valid;

    for (int y = 0, idx = 0; y < height; y++)
    {
        p.xy.y = (float)y;
        for (int x = 0; x < width; x++, idx++)
        {
            p.xy.x = (float)x;

            k4a_calibration_2d_to_3d(
                calibration, &p, 1.f, K4A_CALIBRATION_TYPE_DEPTH, K4A_CALIBRATION_TYPE_DEPTH, &ray, &valid);

            if (valid)
            {
                table_data[idx].xy.x = ray.xyz.x;
                table_data[idx].xy.y = ray.xyz.y;
            }
            else
            {
                table_data[idx].xy.x = nanf("");
                table_data[idx].xy.y = nanf("");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**EDIT2**:
Here is how I have done things in `main.cpp`.

```
k4a_calibration_t calibration;
k4a_image_t xy_table = NULL;
/*
Calibration initialization codes here
*/
create_xy_table(&calibration, xy_table);
```

Comment: compiler error says it all. Function call have`_k4a_image_t*`  but declaration have `_k4a_image_t`

Comment: @ThePhilomath: Does it actually? Please refer to the edit section of my question, I have not used it like you have said in the comment.

Furthermore, why would declaring those non static solve the problem?

Comment: @Evg: On why do I want them to be static, I don't really need those to be static. I already have made those non static and used for my application. But I want to understand what is going on.

Can you kindly elaborate what you mean by "private to this compilation unit"? What do you mean by "compilation unit" here?

Comment: As to @ThePhilomath comment, show your `main.cpp`. It's not clear why it refers to `create_xy_table(_k4a_calibration_t const*, _k4a_image_t*)` (note the asterisk after `_k4a_image_t`).

Comment: @Evg, please refer to **EDIT2** section for main.cpp

Comment: It seems that `k4a_image_t = _k4a_image_t*`. I didn't notice the leading `_`.

Comment: @Evg .. Oh I missed that

Comment: Why have you added the `static` keyword in the first place?

Comment: It was in the SDK's example (Kinect for Azure) [here](https://github.com/microsoft/Azure-Kinect-Sensor-SDK/blob/develop/examples/fastpointcloud/main.cpp) which I tried to break down for my use.

And thank you everyone for the light.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you put implementations into a separate compilation unit (a `.cpp` file) you ask a linker to find these implementations later when objects files are linked together. When you declare a function as [`static`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15235526/the-static-keyword-and-its-various-uses-in-c), you say that this function should not be visible in other compilation units (this is knows as [internal linkage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1358400/what-is-external-linkage-and-internal-linkage)).

Now, you include a header with `static` functions. `utils.cpp` will get its own copies, which will be invisible for all other compilation units. `main.cpp` will see only declarations, but not implementations, so no code will be generated. That's why you get a linking error - the code is in `utils.cpp`, but it is not accessible to anyone.

If you for some reason want to include `static` functions, you should provide their implementation in the header file. Then each compilation unit will get its own private copy of them.

Answer (score 0):

static modifier in c/c++ limits the function definition to one compilation unit (utils.cpp). These functions are then not visible/accessible from other compilation units e.g. main.cpp in your case.