# Is it possible to access static members class in C++ like in Java?

Tags: java, c++, class

In a YouTube video someone made two classes in Java like this:

```java
public class Var {
    static JFrame jf1;
    static int screenWidth = 800;
    static int screenHeight = 600;

    public Var() {
    }
}
```

```java
public class Gui {
    public Gui() {
        Var.jf1 = new JFrame();
        Var.jf1.setSize(Var.screenWidth, Var.screenHeight);
    }
}
```

As you can see he can access `jf1` by just putting `Var.` in front of the variable.

Can you access member variables in C++ like this as well? Or do I have to create a GetValue function which returns the variable I want to have in a different class?

Comment: Did you try it?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [The static keyword and its various uses in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15235526/the-static-keyword-and-its-various-uses-in-c)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In C++, you need to use `Var::jf1`. The `.` syntax is used when you have an object on the left side.

Also, you will need to define the member in your .cpp file:

```
JFrame Var::jf1;
```

Same for the other members.

Comment: "The `.` syntax is used when you have an object on the left side" - Also when you have a reference on the left side