# How to efficiently construct random dice in C++

Tags: c++, private, static-methods, private-members, random-seed

I have a class `dieClass` to represent a six-sided die, and I use `<random>` to set the number. Here is the header file `die.h`:

```
#include <random>
#include <iostream>

class dieClass
{
public:
    dieClass();
    int getNum() const { return num; }

private:
    int num;
    static std::uniform_int_distribution<int> distribution;
};
```

and here is the implementation file `die.cpp`:

```
#include "die.h"

dieClass::dieClass()
{
    static std::random_device rdevice{};
    static std::default_random_engine generator{rdevice()};
    num = distribution(generator);
}

std::uniform_int_distribution<int> dieClass::distribution{1, 6};
```

**Question:** If I call `dieClass dice[5]`, have I created five `default_random_engines`, or just one because it is static? Basically, what would be the most efficient way to construct *millions* of dice? Can I declare `generator` outside of the constructor, like I did for `distribution`? I don't fully understand what private and static do.

**EDIT:** Rearranging things like this seems to achieve what I want, although it may not be best practice. I pulled all random-number-generating code from the class and stuck it in the implementation file. Now I can call `generator` from a function `roll`.

```
dieClass.h
#include <iostream>

class dieClass
{
public:
    die();
    void roll();
    int getNum() const { return num; }

private:
    int num;
};
```

```
dieClass.cpp
#include <random>
#include "die.hpp"

std::random_device rdevice{};
std::default_random_engine generator{rdevice()};
std::uniform_int_distribution<int> distribution{1, 6};

dieClass::dieClass()
{
    num = distribution(generator);
}

void dieClass::roll()
{
    num = distribution(generator);
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [The static keyword and its various uses in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15235526/the-static-keyword-and-its-various-uses-in-c)

Comment: It's static, so it's only one instance. My personal approach would be to not use static members, but let the die class have a generator, a distribution and function to "throw" the die, that generates a new random number. Your current approach seems to be modelling the result of die throw not an actual die that can be thrown many times. But that's just my opinion.

Comment: I would go for the `int getNum() { return distribution(generator); }` approch. Why do you need million of instances of a class that does nothing but randomize 1 number for you? Just call a function and return a different random value each time.

Comment: Those members shouldn't be static. Reusing the generators for multiple die objects completely defeats the purpose of using `random` in the first place. If you want to share those, then, you can just share an object of `dieClass`.

Comment: The second example is the best on. Static is not commonly used and rarely needed. If you won't to create the randomization as a global instances (like in the 2nd example) you can encapsulate it in a class that menage everything, including the creation of dices (dieclass).

Comment: Slightly OT, but seeding a PRNG with the current time is a dangerous practice that is only ok when the PRNG has absolutely no connection to security. For a purely local game, it's fine. But already when the game allows people to upload their high-scores, a clock dependent seed allows for cheating. If you need random numbers of any quality, use `/dev/urandom` or comparable.

Comment: Instead of `static`, consider a `thread_local` generator to avoid data races

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are going to have millions of dice I prefer your second example. It will be more efficient to have one random generator. However, instead of a global random number generator for your dice you can encapsulate it inside a class.

Like static variables you should [avoid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/484635/are-global-variables-bad) the use of globals as much as possible. It is possible to inject a reference or pointer to this new generator class to your `dieClass`. Just change the constructor to accept it. Whenever you want to generate a new number just call a method of the new class.

Here's an example:

```
#include <random>
#include <iostream>

class RandomNumberGenerator
{
public:
    RandomNumberGenerator() : mRd(), mGen(mRd()), mDis(1, 6) {}
    ~RandomNumberGenerator() = default;

    inline int Generate() { return mDis(mGen); }

private:
    std::random_device mRd;
    std::mt19937 mGen;
    std::uniform_int_distribution<int> mDis;
};


class dieClass
{
public:
    dieClass(RandomNumberGenerator &gen) : mGenerator(gen), num(gen.Generate()) {}
    int getNum() const { return num; }
    void roll() { num = mGenerator.Generate(); }

private:
    RandomNumberGenerator &mGenerator;  //store as reference to avoid copying
    int num;
};
```

This way it's the responsibility of the `RandomNumberGenerator` class to generate the randome number, not the `dieClass` class.

Working version [here](https://godbolt.org/z/_iygDZ).