# static qualifier on plain functions in C++

Tags: c++, function, static

I know from C, that the `static` qualifier on functions limits their visibility to the current translation unit. In C I use static, if I define a function in e.g. a `*.c` file, which is intended for use wihtin that file only (mostly specialized helper functions).
I did not find any information on how this is treated in C++. I only found information on how to apply `static` to *member* functions. But in my case, there is no class involved.
As far as I tested it, using `static` on functions in c++ does not produce any compiler warnings and works just fine. Is it acceptable to use it in the same way as in C as stated above? Is it common practice or bad practice?

Comment: Recommended reading: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/keyword/static

Comment: @Casey The cases listed under *Usage* there do not cover plain functions. However, the language seems to allow it.

Comment: @RichardNeumann: It’s the first one, about namespace members.

Comment: Section (B) of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43442151/3515670) answered my question. tl;dr: Yes, it's the same as in C.