# Simple demostration of Call by Reference to pointer not working

Tags: c++, pass-by-reference

Here is my simple demostration of `Call by Reference` to pointer in C++:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void myMethod(int* &x) {
    int t = 4;
    int* pt = &t;
    cout << "Address of t: " << pt << endl;
    cout << "Value of t: " << *pt << endl;
    
    x = pt;
    cout << "Address of x: " << x << endl;
    cout << "Value of x: " << *x << endl;
}

int main() {
    int y = 5;
    int* py = &y;
    cout << "Address of y: " << py << endl;
    cout << "Value of y: " << *py << endl;
    
    myMethod(py);
    cout << "Address of y after method: " << py << endl;
    cout << "Value of y after method: " << *py;
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
Address of y: 0x7ced454457cc
Value of y: 5
Address of t: 0x7ced4544579c
Value of t: 4
Address of x: 0x7ced4544579c
Value of x: 4
Address of y after method: 0x7ced4544579c
Value of y after method: 31205
```

I am passing the reference of the `pointer to y` as an argument to the method `myMethod()`. In the method, the passed reference is assigned a new `pointer to t`, which in turn reassigns the `pointer to y` i.e., `py = pt`. Hence, after the method, when the `pointer to y` is printed, it prints the correct pointer which is the `pointer to t`. So, if we now print the dereferenced value of `pointer to y`, it should print the value `4`. However, it prints some random number.

**Why the `Value of y after method` is some random number, and not equal to `4`?**

Comment: `int t = 4; int* pt = &t; x = pt;` makes it point to a local variable that goes out of scope when the function ends.

Comment: But the address is preserved. Isn't that enough to retain the variable?

Comment: No. The program is free to reuse that memory once the variable goes out of scope. Trying to read it is "Undefined Behavior".

Comment: Thanks, now it works. The solution is to make the local variable ```t``` a global variable.

Comment: You could also make it [`static`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15235626/669576).