# C++ static function split into hpp/cpp files

Tags: c++, function, compiler-errors, static

I have the following files:

- `includes/static.hpp`:

```cpp
#ifndef STATIC_HPP_
#define STATIC_HPP_

namespace static_namespace {
    static void static_function();
    static inline void static_inline_function();
}

#endif
```

- `src/static.cpp`:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include "static.hpp"

using namespace std;
using namespace static_namespace;

static void static_namespace::static_function(){
    cout<<"Static"<<endl;
}
static inline void static_namespace::static_inline_function() {
    cout<<"Static inline"<<endl;
}
```

- `src/main.cpp`:

```cpp
#include "static.hpp"

using namespace std;
using namespace static_namespace;

int main (int argc, const char *argv[]) {
    static_function();
    static_inline_function();
    return 0;
}
```

The full project can be found [here](https://github.com/matheusdiogenesandrade/static_cpp_test).

When compiling the above files, the following message appears:

```bash
[ 50%] Linking CXX executable main
/usr/bin/ld: CMakeFiles/main.dir/src/main.cpp.o: in the function `main':
main.cpp:(.text.startup+0x9): reference to `static_namespace::static_function()' not defined
/usr/bin/ld: main.cpp:(.text.startup+0xe): reference to `static_namespace::static_inline_function()' not defined
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/main.dir/build.make:97: main] Error 1
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:83: CMakeFiles/main.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [Makefile:91: all] Error 2
```

Is it possible to define the implementation of a static function separatedly from its declaration?

Thanks and regards.

Comment: `Is it possible to define the implementation of a static function separatedly from its declaration?` No. Whats the point of making it static if you want to compile it seperately?

Comment: related https://stackoverflow.com/a/15235626/4117728

Comment: you can split declaration and definition. What you cannot do is use the function defined in `static.cpp` from `main.cpp`, because it has internal linkage