# How to obtain a vector of object from static member of types indexed by enum?

Tags: c++, templates

I have an Enum type and an type indexed by it.

```cpp
enum class E{
    a, b, c, d, ..., count
};

template<E e>
class C{
};

template<>
class C<E::a>{
    static int fn(){
        return 1;
    };
};
// ... similar definition for E::b, E::c
```

how shall write a function that return the a static vector containing each of the member indexed by the enum? use variadic template maybe?

```cpp
const static std::vector<const std::function<int(void)>>& 
return_array(){
static std::vector<const std::function<int()>> a;
...
return a;
}
```

Comment: References are not objects in C++, so you cannot have array of references.

Comment: *"how shall i obtain an array of reference..."* You can't.

Comment: Also, `std::array` require two template argument, while in your example you only gave/provided 1.

Comment: Don't change the question entirely after there are already answer(s) such that it invalidates the answers.. It wastes people's time and effort in giving/writing the answer. You can ask a new separate question.

Answer (score 0):

First note that we cannot have array(or vector etc) of references in C++. You can use `std::cref`(see method 1).

Second, `std::array` require two template arguments while in your code you've only provided one.

Thus to solve this remove the reference `&` and pass the second argument two the `std::array` as shown below. Note also that there are **multiple ways** to do what you want.

##### Method 1

Here we use `std::cref`.

```
static std::array<std::function<int()>,3>  
return_array()
{
    //use std::cref
    static std::array<std::function<int()>,3> a{std::cref(C<E::a>::fn), std::cref(C<E::b>::fn), std::cref(C<E::c>::fn)}; 
    return a;   
}
```

[Working demo](https://godbolt.org/z/s5oTqYxKG)

##### Method 2

Here we just remove the reference `&` since we can't have array or vector of references.

```
//-----------------------------------------v----->removed reference from here
static std::array<const std::function<int()>,3>  
//-------------------------------------------^--->pass the second argument
return_array()
{
    static std::array<const std::function<int()>,3> a{&C<E::a>::fn, &C<E::b>::fn, &C<E::c>::fn };
    return a;   
}
```

[Working demo](https://godbolt.org/z/h9hbfa89M)

---

##### Method 3

Other **alternative** is to use normal pointer to function.

```
//use normal pointer to function
static std::array<int(*)(),3>  return_array()
{
    static std::array<int(*)(),3> a{&C<E::a>::fn, &C<E::b>::fn, &C<E::c>::fn };
    return a;   
}
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/9e1vqTcE3)

---

Also [The static keyword and its various uses in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15235526/the-static-keyword-and-its-various-uses-in-c)

Comment: While we cannot have vectors of references, we *can* have vectors of pointers or `std::reference_wrapper`s. That may be useful to OP.

Comment: @JesperJuhl Yes, I added `std::cref`(in method 1). Now there are three way to solve this all of which are shown in the answer.