# What are the properties of const char*?

Tags: c++, string, pointers, char, constants

I am really confused what is exactly const in const char is because i can change the value. Is the Pointer const or what is this? and what is the difference to const char or char* or char const???

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the difference between const int\*, const int \* const, and int const \*?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1143262/what-is-the-difference-between-const-int-const-int-const-and-int-const)

Comment: It is an array of `const char`, the pointer itself is not `const`.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2812875/how-const-keyword-works-in-c  ,
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4949254/const-char-const-versus-const-char/4949283 and 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1143262/what-is-the-difference-between-const-int-const-int-const-and-int-const

Answer (score 2):

```
char * p = ...
```

is a pointer to a char. You can change the pointer, as well as the value the pointer is pointing to.

```
char const * p = ...
const char * p = ...
```

are equivalent, and are pointers to a `char const`. The pointer can be pointed anywhere, but it must always point to a `char const`.

```
char const * const p = ...
const char * const p = ...
```

are equivalent, and declare a `const` pointer to a `char const`. You can't change what the pointer is pointing to, or the value at what the pointer is pointing to.

```
char * const p = ...
```

is a `const` pointer to a char. You can change the value that is pointed to, but you can't change the pointer to point somewhere else.

Answer (score 1):

> I am really confused what is exactly const in const char

The `char` is const. I.e. the pointed type is `const char`.

> because i can change the value.

Indeed, the pointer is not const, therefore it can be made to point elsewhere by changing its value.

> Is the Pointer const

No. It is a non-const pointer to const.

> and what is the difference to const char

It is a non-mutable character.

> or char*

It is a pointer to a character.

> or char const???

Same as `const char`.

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't change the value.

```
const char* ptr = "thing";
ptr[2] = 'o';  // error
```

It's a pointer to `const char`s.

You can, however, make the pointer point to something else, because it's not a `const char* const`. :)

Const applies to the left, unless there's nothing there, in which case it applies to the right.

Comment: thanks for the help, it makes things clear