# Why doesn't this C program compile? What is wrong with this?

Tags: c

Why doesn't this C program compile? What is wrong with this?

I have tried it on `wxDevC++` and Turbo C++ 3.0.

### Main.c

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>

const int SIZE = 5;

int main(int argc, char ** argv)
{    
    char array[SIZE] = {'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E'};

    printf("Array elements are,\n");
    int i=0;

    for(i=0 ; i<SIZE ; ++i)
    {
        printf("%c  ", array[i]);
    }

    getch();

    return 0;
}
```

Error Messages on the both of the compilers are similar.

```
f:\_Source-Codes\main.c In function `main':

8 f:\_Source-Codes\main.c variable-sized object may not be initialized
```

Comment: what are errors?

Comment: I don't see any problems immediately... what error are you seeing?

Comment: It compiles just fine in Visual Studio 2005.

Comment: @Neil Butterworth sorry for non IT question, but what is "pile of pooh"?

Comment: Your compiler doesn't allow variable sized arrays. Simply replace array[SIZE] with array[5] /or/ replace const int SIZE = 5; with #define SIZE 5 and it will compile (at least for that error).

Comment: "pile of pooh" = A large heap of not very intelligent bears - not something you want in a dev tool

Comment: Turbo C++ 3.0, the first C++ compiler I ever used in about 1992. This question must be a joke!

Comment: @Chapso, VS2008 is not compiling. Error 1 error C2057: expected constant expression f:\_source-codes\main.c 8 ArrayInit__in__C

Comment: @Daniel Earwicker, I was just testing it in TC++. Meet Jim Cerry.

Comment: @Daniel Earwicker: Joke or not, the result will be the same in any conforming C89/90 compiler, i.e. at least a diagnostic message about a constraint violation.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Array size in C89/90 language must be specified by an integral *constant expression* (in general true for C99 as well). A `const int` object in C is not a *constant expression*, which is why you can't use it to specify array size. Note: this is one prominent difference between C and C++.

In C language the term *constant* refers to *literal* constants, i.e. `5`, `10.2`, `0xFF`, `'a'` and so on (enum constants are also *constants*, to be precise). `const int` object, once again, is not a *constant* in C and cannot be used to build constant expressions.

If you want to pre-declare a named constant to be used as array size in C, you have to use either `#define` or `enum`. The same applies to case labels, bit-field sizes and every other context requiring a constant expression.

See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2308194/shall-i-prefer-constants-over-defines/2308364#2308364) for more details.

Comment: Is this allowed in C++?  If I did `const int SIZE = someFunction();`, the compiler wouldn't know at compile-time how much stack-space is needed for `char array[SIZE]`...

Comment: @BlueRaja: In C++ constant expressions can use `const` objects *initialized with constant expressions*. In your case, your `const` object is not initialized with a constant expression, which is why it is by itself not a constant.

Comment: @AndreyT, Then what is the use of const-keyword in C?

Comment: @Andrey: any links as to what constitutes a *constant expression*?  What if someFunction() is defined as `const int someFunction() { return 5; }` - would SIZE then be considered initialized with a constant expression?

Comment: @JMSA: `const` only means that you can't change the value of the variable later - the initial value itself may not be a constant expression.

@BlueRaja: I guess that depends on whether the compiler decides to expand `someFunction` inline.

Comment: @JMSA: `const` keyword in C is used to declare objects that should not be changed at run-time (and to declare const-qualified access paths to objects). It doesn't introduce compile-time constants, which is why it has significantly more limited use in C than in C++.

Comment: @BlueRaja: No. In todays C++ the result of a function call is never a constant expression, regardless of whether it is inline or not. In future C++ standard a new keyword is coming up (`constexpr` or something like that) that would allow you to declare functions that can be used in constant expressions. This is exactly what would apply to your function.

Answer (score 8):

if the compiler is treating it as a '.c' file, the `int i` declaration needs to before any executable lines, speficically, before the `printf`.

EDIT, now that you showed the error message:

The compiler does not consider `SIZE` as a constant when compiling main.  You could use `#define SIZE 5` as a work-around.

According to K&R 2nd Ed. :

> "The purpose of `const` is to announce objects that may be placed in read-only
>   memory. ... Except that it should diagnose
>   explicit attempts to change *const*
>   objects, a compiler may ignore [the
>   const] qualifier".

So declaring `const int SIZE = 5` does not make `SIZE` a *constant-expression*, which is what an array size specifier requires.

Comment: Yes. But why doesn't const work? What does ANSI standard says?

Comment: Correct, the declaration has to proceed the method.

Comment: maybe because Turbo C++ 3.0 is almost 20 years old

Comment: @fuzzy lollipop, OK but I have also tested it on wxDevC++ and VS2008.

Comment: @AShelly: Strictly speaking, your quite from K&R is irrelevant. A `const` object in C language is *never* a *constant*. The term *constant* in C has a completely different meaning. *Constant* in C terminology is what we call *literal* in C++ (like `5`, `0x1` or `'a'`). A `const int` object is not a constant in C and cannot be used where a *constant expression* is required. This is always true, regardless of the compiler and of whether it ignores "something" or not.

Comment: @AndreyT: Diving into K&R a little further, I see that it says the same thing.  Editing my answer to clarify.

Answer (score 5):

Try replacing

```
const int SIZE = 5;
```

with

```
#define SIZE 5
```

Most C compilers don't allow declaring static arrays whose sizes are contained in variables (i.e. the array size is determined at runtime).

Comment: Most? What compilers do allow declaring *static* arrays "whose sizes are contained in variables"?

Comment: @AndreyT: Just trying to be safe rather than sorry.

Answer (score 3):

try this:

```
char array[] = {'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E'};
```

Comment: @overslacked, This is not true.  The size depends first on the constant specified.  `char array[2] = {'a','b','c'};` generates an error.   `char array[3] = {'a','b'};` generates a 3 element array.  The size is only infered from the initializer list if the `[]`s are empty.