# How come the compiler thinks this variable isn't constant?

Tags: c++, c, compiler-construction, compiler-errors

This is my code:

```
int main()
{
 const int LEN = 5;
 int x[LEN];
}
```

VS10 says:

> error C2057: expected constant
>   expression
>
> error C2466: cannot allocate an array
>   of constant size 0
>
> error C2133: 'x' : unknown size

I even tried the the code in this page and it gives the same problem (I commented the code which gives the error, and uncommented the correct one):
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/eff825eh%28VS.71%29.aspx

If I was trying a crappy compiler, I would think it's a bug in the compiler, but it's VS2010!

Comment: check that LEN hasn't been #defined somewhere?

Comment: My question is why aren't you using a `#define` for this?

Comment: @William: `#define`s are not a good way to define constants, because they use the preprocessor and lack typing information and such; newer languages often don't even have the equivalent. Constants like this are better practice in most situations.

Comment: @sje397 I'm sure there aren't any #define in the source code.

Comment: It's bad because what you're seeing isn't what you're getting -- it's text that will be replaced, and you have no idea if it's an `int`, `long long`, etc. Furthermore, it has no scope or anything... see this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1674032/static-const-vs-define-in-c

Comment: instead of being sure, just try with #undef LEN, or use __len for example... uppercase is used for macros and defines

Comment: @Lambert: Apparently you don't know C. `const` variables are nearly useless in C. They certainly don't define constants.

Comment: @Lambert Ok; your edit made it clearer. Thanks

Comment: @R: This is C++ too, though, right?

Comment: All the #defines are global, that's why they are bad. One day you'll want to #define another LEN somewhere below in this unit. It's not a really big deal when all the #defines in one .cpp unit, but can still be annoying.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You might have compiled your code using .c extension. MS Visual C doesn't support C99. In C89 the size of an array must be a constant expression. `const` qualified variables are not **constants** in C. They cannot be used at places where a real *constant* is required.

Also read [this excellent post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2308194/shall-i-prefer-constants-over-defines/2308364#2308364) by AndreyT.

Try saving the file with .cpp extension.

Comment: Works for me in gcc, no matter what dialect of C I specify. But I think you might be on to something as far as tweaking Visual Studio.

Comment: @Jon : gcc supports C99 and Variable Length Arrays are part of C99, so the code works in gcc. The code is valid in C99 and C++.

Comment: @Jon With `-ansi`, GCC gives `warning: ISO C90 forbids variable-size array ‘x’`

Answer (score 2):

As per http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3ffb821x.aspx, "Values declared as const that are initialized with constant expressions" are legal in array bounds, so this is valid C++ code.

Thus, that's either a compiler bug or something bizarre coming off a #define somewhere.  As sje397's comment suggests, try some name other than `LEN` for the length?  Also, is that actually your entire code, or are headers being #included as well?

Edit to add: Also, the fact that this is valid C++ code of course doesn't matter if you're compiling this as C, as others have noted.

Comment: It's more like a not implemented feature rather than a serious bug. I had the same problem when porting my code from G++ to some other compiler, I don't remember which one though.

Comment: I'd argue that in C++ it's a serious bug (it's pretty basic that a constant expression should in fact be a constant expression), while in C99 the bug would be a not-implemented-feature of variable-length arrays.  But a fair point.

Answer (score 2):

You could also use

```
int main()
{
    enum { LEN = 5 };
    int x[LEN];
}
```

Comment: This works. Tested right now with VS2015. Language extensions disabled as well. The crappy thing is that Microsoft in their documentation uses a example that doesn't work https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/eff825eh(VS.71).aspx

Answer (score 1):

because in this case, I can do :

```
int main()
{
    const int LEN = 5;
    int* LENptr = (int*)(&LEN);
    *LENptr = 10;
    int x[LEN];
}
```

which const is only means read-only in this code, not compile-time constant

Comment: This "sample" exhibits undefined behaviour so you can't infer anything about the language from its behaviour.

Comment: You can write that code, and can perhaps compile it, but does casting away the constness of your pointer-target actually mean that it's legal C++ to then change its value?  I don't think so.  If I add `printf("%d\n", LEN);` to the end of that code, and compile it with g++ and run it, it prints 5, not 10.  I'm almost surprised it doesn't segfault.

Comment: I just tried your code (for science :), but LEN never changed. So, maybe it is as Bailey said "undefined behaviour".

Comment: Of course, I realize the original poster didn't say whether this was C++ or C, and I just assumed from the C++ tag that it was C++ -- I didn't see the C tag.

Comment: It definitely will segfault on some platforms. That happened to me once.