# What does the following mean in context of programming, specifically C programming language?

Tags: c, types

> representations of values on a computer can vary “culturally” from architecture to architecture or are determined by the type the programmer gave to the value. Therefore, we should try to reason primarily about values and not about representations if we want to write portable code.
>
> Specifying values. We have already seen several ways in which numerical constants (literals) can be specified:
>
> 123 Decimal integer constant.
> 077 Octal integer constant.
> 0xFFFF Hexadecimal integer constant.
> et cetera

Question: Are decimal integer constants and hexadecimal integer constants, different ways to 'represent' values or are they values themselves? If the latter what are different ways to represent them on different architectures?

The source of the aforementioned is the book "Modern C" by Jens Gustedt which is [freely available online](https://hal.inria.fr/hal-02383654/document), specifically from page no. 38 to page no. 46.

Comment: C does not _reify_ the radix used with an integer literal, so different literal representations have the same binary/compiled/internal representation. So, as far as a C program is concerned, there is **no difference** between `int x = 0xFF;` and `int x = 255;`.

Comment: Note that in C, [a _constant_ and a _literal_ are not the same thing](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11732795/159145)

Comment: I don't know what the quote you give means, but perhaps the "representation of a value" is the actual bit pattern.  For example, some machines store a multibyte integer with the individual bytes in one order and other machines use a different order (big-endian vs little-endian).  But both bit pattens represent the exact smae value - it is just stored differently.  The same is true with ones-compliment and twos-complement signed integers (although I don't think the Standard supports anything except twos-complement singed integers any more - but I could be wrong about that)

Comment: Maybe I am wrong about the ones compliment signed integers not being supported: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12276957/are-there-any-non-twos-complement-implementations-of-c https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6971886/exotic-architectures-the-standards-committees-care-about

Comment: @JerryJeremiah Yes, the C standard specifies very little about the binary representation of data types, but e.g. the minimal range for `int` is from - 32767 to 32767, which clearly can be implemented with ones' complement representation.

Comment: In C, a "literal" is a compile-time concept (ie: something that appears in source code), and a "value" is a run-time concept (ie: the contents of an object), so they're not the same . A literal doesn't "represent" a value in the sense that it doesn't describe the (run-time) representation of a runtime value. But a lot hinges on exactly what you mean by all of the significant words in your question.

Comment: Please cite sources. You have two quotes with no sources. Sources should always always _always_ be cited, with links ideally, but in other ways at least.

Comment: I interpret the first quoted paragraph to mean that to write portable code, one should not make assumptions about how data is laid out in memory (for example, assuming big- or little- endian, or that integers are a certain number of bits, or even that bytes have 8 bits, or that structs don't have padding, or ...).

Comment: This is much to vague. "Representation of values" can mean anything from integers to floats to structs to strings. I don't see why the dec/hex/octal constants have anything to do with that, it's a completely unrelated matter.

Answer (score 4):

The words "representation" can be used here in two different contexts.

One is when we (the programmers) specify e.g. integer constants. For example, the value 37 may be represented in the C code as `37` or `0x25` or `045`. Regardless of which representation we have chosen, the C compiler will interpret this into the same value when generating the binary code. Hence, these statements all generate the same code:

```
  int a = 37;
  int a = 0x25;
  int a = 045;
```

Another context is how the compiler chooses to store the value `37` internally. The C standard states a few requirements (e.g. that the representation of `int` must at least be able to represent values in the range `-32767` to `+32767`). Within the rules of the C standard the compiler will use a bit representation which can be operated on efficiently by the native language of the target system's CPU. The most common representation for signed integers is [Two's complement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement) and usually a signed integer with type `int` will occupy 2 or 4 bytes of 8 bits each.

However, the C standard is sufficiently flexible to allow for other internal representations (e.g. bytes with more than 8 bits or [Ones' complement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ones%27_complement) representation of signed integers). A common difference between representations of multibyte integers on different systems is the use of different [byte order](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness).

The C standard is primarily concerned with the result of standard operations. E.g. `5+6` must give the same result no matter on which platform the expression is executed, but how `5`, `6` and `11` are represented on the given platform is largely up to the compiler to decide.

Comment: Good explanations (especially the part about "representation" having at least two meanings in this context), except that the preprocessor has nothing to do with the integer literals.

Comment: @Peter-ReinstateMonica. Thank you, and you are of course right. I have updated the answer accordingly. Thank you for pointing this out.

Answer (score 3):

It is of utmost importance to every C programmer to understand that **C is an abstraction layer that shields you from the underlying hardware**. This service is the *raison d'être* for the language, the reason it was developed.  Among other things, the language shields you from the different internal byte patterns used to hold the same values on different platforms: You write a value and operations on it, and the compiler will see to producing the proper code. This would be different in assembler where you are intimately concerned with memory layout, register sizes etc.

In case it wasn't obvious: I'm emphasizing this because I struggled with these concepts myself when I learned C.

The first thing to hammer down is that **C program code is text.** What we deal with here are **text representations of values,** a succession of (most likely) ASCII codes much as if you wrote a letter to your grandma.

Integer literals like 0443 (the less usual octal format), 0x0123 or 291 are simply different string representations for the same value. Here and in the standard, "value" is a value in the mathematical sense. As much as we think "oh, C!" when we see "0x0123", it is nothing else than a way to write down the mathematical value of 291. That's meant with "value", for example when the standard specifies that "the type of an integer constant is the first of the corresponding list in which its value can be represented." The compiler has to create a binary representation of that value in the program's memory. This means it has to find out what value it is (291 in all cases) and then produce the proper byte pattern for it. **The integer literal in the C code is not a binary form of anything,** no matter whether you choose to write its string representation down base 10, base 16 or base 8. In particular does `0x0123` not mean that the two bytes `01` and `23` will be anywhere in the compiled program, or in which order.<sup>1</sup>

To demonstrate the abstraction consider the expression `(0x0123 << 4) == 0x1230`, which should be true on all machines. Both hex literals are of type `int` here. The beauty of hex code is that it makes bit manipulations in multiples of 4 really easy to compute.

On a typical contemporary Intel architecture an `int` has 4 bytes and is organized "little endian first", or "little endian" for short: The lowest-value byte comes first if we inspect the memory in ascending order. 0x123 is represented as 00100011-00000001-00000000-00000000 (because the two highest-value bytes are zero for such a small number). 0x1230 is, consequently, 00110000-00010010-00000000-00000000. *No left-shift whatsoever* took place on the hardware (but also no right-shift!). The bit-shift operators' semantics are an abstraction: "*Imagine* a regular binary number, following the old Arab fashion of starting with the highest-value digit, and shift that *imagined binary number.*" It is an abstraction that bears zero resemblance to anything happening on the hardware, and the compiler simply translates this abstract operation into the right thing *for that particular hardware.*

---

<sub><sup>1</sup>Now admittedly, they probably are there, but on your prevalent x86 platform their order will be reversed, as assumed below.</sub>

Comment: And if you want an even more mind-expanding journey into the difference between text representations versus hardware values, consider the three *very* different numbers that are involved when you say `float f = 0.1; printf("%.10f\n", f);`.

Answer (score 2):

> Are decimal integer constants and hexadecimal integer constants, different ways to 'represent' values or are they values themselves?

This is philosophy! They are different ways to represent values, like:

```
  0x2          means 2 (for a C compiler)
  two          means 2 (english language)
  a couple     means 2 (for an english speaker)
  zwei         means 2 (...)
```

A C compiler translates from "some form of human understandable language" to "a very precise form understandable by the machine": the only thing which is retained from the various forms, is the intimate meaning (the value!).

It happens that C, in order to be more friendly, lets you specify integers in two different ways, decimal and hexadecimal (ok, even octal and recently also binary notation). What the C compiler is interested in, is the **value** and, as already noted in a comment, after the C has "understand" the value, there is no more difference between a "0xC" or a "12". From that point, the compiler must make the machine understand the value 12, using the *representation* the target machine uses and, again, what is important is the value.

Most probably, the phrase

> we should try to reason primarily about values and not about representations

is an invite to the programmers to choose correct data types and values, but not only: also to give useful names for types and variables and so on. A not very good example is: even if we know that a line feed is represented (often) by a 10 decimal, we should use LF or "\n" or similar, which is the value we want, not its representation.

About data types, especially integers, C is not particularly brilliant, compared to other languages which let you define types based on their possible values (for example with the "-3 .. 5" notation, which states that the possible values go from -3 to 5, and lets the compiler choose the number of bits needed for the **representation** of the range -3 to 5).