# Why const a + const b is not a const itself?

Tags: c

I am making a pong clone to test a SDK... It is some years that I don't C.

Anyway, I tried to do this in the const setup phase:

```
const int SCREEN_W = 480;
const int SCREEN_H = 480;
const int PLAYER_H_WIDTH = 50;
const int PLAYER_H_HEIGHT = 12;
const int BUFFER = 14;
const int LEFT_BUFFER = PLAYER_H_WIDTH+BUFFER;
const int RIGHT_BUFFER = SCREEN_W-LEFT_BUFFER;
```

except the compiler throws a error at `LEFT_BUFFER` and `RIGHT_BUFFER` lines, thus making me wonder, why?

If the answer is "because the standard says so" I still want to know why (why the standard says so?)

EDIT because of comments:

haccks noticed that those lines inside a function (like, main(){}) do compile, while on file scope they don't. I also ask, why?

Also the specific GCC (actually MingW) error is: `initializer element is not constant`

Comment: When asking questions about a compiler error, it's always helpful to include the text of the error. It wouldn't hurt to mention which compiler you're using, too.

Comment: It is MingW, that says that I tried to init LEFT_BUFFER and RIGHT_BUFFER with something that is not a const. I thought this was implicit from the title.

Comment: I compiled it with GCC and getting no error.

Comment: @haccks I compiled it with gcc4.8.1 and get "error: initializer element is not a constant" in C90, C99 and C11 mode.

Comment: @haccks Try giving the variables global (or file) scope

Comment: @dyp; The compile this `#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{

const int SCREEN_W = 480;
const int SCREEN_H = 480;
const int PLAYER_H_WIDTH = 50;
const int PLAYER_H_HEIGHT = 12;
const int BUFFER = 14;
const int LEFT_BUFFER = PLAYER_H_WIDTH+BUFFER;
const int RIGHT_BUFFER = SCREEN_W-LEFT_BUFFER;

return 0;
}
` The only expected warning is about unused variables.

Comment: Here on my system I left those on file scope.

Comment: @haccks As simonc said, use global or static variables. The problem is C99 6.7.8/4 "All the expressions in an initializer for an object that has static storage duration shall be
constant expressions or string literals."

Comment: @dyp; I understand now. Sorry for that. But OP should have mentioned this in the question.

Comment: @haccks I did not even knew it made a difference :P

Comment: @speeder; In programming every bit may make a difference :)

Comment: @speeder Note that the `const` is (seems to be) irrelevant: The static storage duration is what makes it illegal.

Comment: @speeder Also note that the example is legal in C++. So it's a deliberate restriction in C, or maybe a simplification.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Shall I prefer constants over defines?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2308194/shall-i-prefer-constants-over-defines)

Comment: Also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1674032/static-const-vs-define-in-c

Answer (score 6, accepted):

An initializer for an object declared with static storage duration (outside any function, or inside a function with the `static` keyword) must be a constant expression, or must contain only constant expressions.

This declaration:

```
const int PLAYER_H_WIDTH = 50;
```

does *not* make `PLAYER_H_WIDTH` a constant expression. The keyword `const` really doesn't mean "constant" (i.e., able to be evaluated at compile time); it means "read-only".

So when you declare:

```
const int LEFT_BUFFER = PLAYER_H_WIDTH+BUFFER;
```

you're trying to initialize `LEFT_BUFFER` with a non-constant expression.

Reference: ISO C standard, 2011 edition, section 6.7.9 paragraph 4:

> All the expressions in an initializer for an object that has static or
>   thread storage duration shall be constant expressions or string
>   literals.

To illustrate the difference between `const` and `constant`, this:

```
const int r = rand();
```

is a perfectly valid declaration, as long as it's not at file scope. The object (I don't want to call it a "variable") `r` is *const* (i.e., read-only), but not *constant* (i.e., its value can't be determined at compile time).

That declaration cannot appear outside any function because of C's execution model, which doesn't allow user code to be executed before `main` is entered.

C++ does make such objects constant *if* the initializer is constant and of integer type; C does not. The rule in C++ requires a bit more work by the compiler; it make the determination of whether an object's name is a constant expression dependent on the the form of its initializer. I'm not sure why C hasn't adopted the C++ rule; probably the committee didn't feel it was worthwhile (remember that any new feature imposes a burden on every compiler implementer).

As a workaround, you can either use the preprocessor:

```
#define PLAYER_H_WIDTH 50
/* ... */
#define LEFT_BUFFER (PLAYER_H_WIDTH+BUFFER)
```

or you can use a slightly ugly hack with `enum`:

```
enum { PLAYER_H_WIDTH = 50 };
enum { LEFT_BUFFER = PLAYER_H_WIDTH+BUFFER };
```

The latter works only for constants of type `int`.  The trick is that an `enum` declaration creates an enumeration type, but the enumerators are still of type `int`.

Comment: *"(C++ does make such objects constant; C does not.)"* That leads to the question: Why? Is it the principle "Provide only one way to do an operation."?

Comment: @dyp: I think it's just historical inertia.

Comment: "C++ does make such objects constant if the initializer is constant;" - Only for integer types. For other types, even if the initializer is constant, the object is not.

Answer (score 1):

Your question title shows that you've been misled by some confusion. It has nothing to do with `a + b` or `a - b`. You will get the same error if you just do

```
const int LEFT_BUFFER = BUFFER;
```

without any `+` or `-`.

The problem is that none of the names you defined are "constants", meaning that they cannot form constant expressions. For example, `SCREEN_W` is not a constant.

In C language the term "constant" applies to literal values (like `42`) and to enum constants. Variables declared as `const` are not "constants" in C language. You can call them "const variables" if you want, but you will never be able to use them where true constants are required.

That is just the way it is in C. That is how it has always been in C. If you want to declare a manifest constant in C language, use `#define` or `enum`. Don't attempt to use `const`. `const` has some pleasant properties (compared to `#define`), but the fact that `const` does not produce true constants in C severely limits the usability of `const` for declaring manifest constants.

Your original example actually demonstrates the issue. Objects with static storage duration require constant initializers in C. Since your `PLAYER_H_WIDTH`, `BUFFER` etc. are *not* constants, you cannot use them as initializers for objects with static storage duration. And, again, the problem has nothing to do with `+` or `-`, it is present even in

```
const int LEFT_BUFFER = BUFFER;
```

declaration.

If you transfer these lines into local scope, your objects will no longer have static storage duration. They will become local variables. The aforementioned restriction does not apply to local variables, which is why your declarations will compile without any problems. However, if you add the keyword `static` to the above declarations, the error will reappear even in local scope.

Answer (score 0):

C's constant is not actually a "constant" as we expected. It is an indicator to the compiler that the variable's content could not be changed. The initialize needs to be constant expressions or string literals.

The closest thing to a constant in C is using enum or #define, e.g.

```
 enum {
    SCREEN_W = 480,
    SCREEN_H = 480,
    PLAYER_H_WIDTH = 50,
    PLAYER_H_HEIGHT = 12,
    BUFFER = 14,
    LEFT_BUFFER = PLAYER_H_WIDTH+BUFFER,
    RIGHT_BUFFER = SCREEN_W-LEFT_BUFFER
 };
```

I would use enum as far as I could.

Answer (score 0):

use The #define directive preprocessor if  you want to avoid this error !

```
const int SCREEN_W = 480;
const int SCREEN_H = 480;
const int PLAYER_H_WIDTH = 50;
const int PLAYER_H_HEIGHT = 12;
const int BUFFER = 14;
#define  LEFT_BUFFER  PLAYER_H_WIDTH + BUFFER
#define  RIGHT_BUFFER  SCREEN_W - LEFT_BUFFER
```

The #define directive is a preprocessor directive; the preprocessor replaces those macros by their body before the compiler even sees it. Think of it as an automatic search and replace of your source code.

But a constant defined with the const qualifier is best thought of as an unmodifiable variable. It has all the properties of a variable: it has a type, it has a size, it has linkage, you can take its address.

for this the compiler can't compile the assignment of const variable to another, because the assigned variable is not a constant expression.

Comment: `#define const int LEFT_BUFFER`? and no parens?

Comment: const value + const value = const value but is not const expression  that can be assigned to another const variable. is a compilator behaviour

Comment: @Anis_Stack: This does not have anything to do with any "compilator behavior". `value + value` is always an rvalue, which cannot be const or non-const at all. And it makes no sense whatsoever to mix `const` and `#define` like that. Just use `#define` in all cases, how it is normally donw in `C.