# In C how is this parameter declared in the function?

Tags: c, function

I am trying to learn the basics of C using [The C Programming Language - Brian Kernighan and Dennis Ritchie](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_C_Programming_Language)

In the program below, I don't understand where the value for `'maxlineLength`' comes from?

The for loop is set to run while '`i`' is smaller than `maxLineLength-1`, but what is the value of `maxLineLength` and where does it come from?

From what I understand, when parameters are declared in a function like this a value is being passed to them, so they must surely be declared somewhere else to have the value passed in?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define MAXIMUMLINELENGTH 1000
#define LONGLINE 20

main() {
 int stringLength;
 char line[MAXIMUMLINELENGTH];

  while((stringLength = getLineLength(line, MAXIMUMLINELENGTH)) > 0)
    if(stringLength < LONGLINE){
  printf("The line was under the minimum length\n");
    }
    else if (stringLength > LONGLINE){
        printf("%s", line);
    }
  return 0;
}


int getLineLength(char line[], int maxLineLength){
  int i, c;

  for(i = 0; i< maxLineLength-1 && ((c = getchar())!= EOF) && c != '\n'; i++)
    line[i] = c;

  if(c == '\n') {
      line[i] = c;
      i++;
  }

  line[i] = '\0';
  return i;
}
```

Comment: defined as macro `#define MAXIMUMLINELENGTH 1000` passes to function `getLineLength()` in while

Comment: Hi Grijesh are MAXIMUMLINELENGTH and maxLineLength two completely different variables?

Comment: `MAXIMUMLINELENGTH` is constant that expands to value `1000`at compilation time, Yes `maxLineLength` is different variable local to function `getLineLength()` , get an idea over [macro const from here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3216752/what-is-the-difference-between-macro-constants-and-constant-variables-in-c)

Comment: But if I change maxLineLength to LengthLineMax so it bears no relation to MAXLINELENGTH what so ever the program still runs correctly so i still dont understand where the value comes from?

Comment: When you call `getLineLength(line, MAXIMUMLINELENGTH)`, `MAXIMUMLINELENGTH` copy to function variable, you can use any name of variable `maxLineLength` or `LineLength` it doesn't matter its value passed at function call

Comment: your welcome,  you should also read 5 answer posted below all are good!, And accept at-lest one by click on right

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> From what I understand, when parameters are declared in a function like this a value is being passed to them, so they must surely be declared somewhere else to have the value passed in?

In this case, the function is being declared and defined at the same time. Pre-ANSI C allowed that. This is considered a bad practice today. You should add a forward declaration

```
int getLineLength(char line[], int maxLineLength);
```

above `main` in order to avoid declaring the function implicitly.

When this forward declaration is missing, the first use of the function becomes its implicit declaration. The compiler takes types of the expression parameters that you pass, and assumes that the function takes corresponding types as its parameters. It also assumes that the function returns an `int`. In this case the compiler has all the information necessary to figure out the correct signature, so the function is defined correctly. However, in more complex cases (say, if `maxLineLength` was declared as `long long`, not `int`) it would lead to undefined behavior, so you should always include a forward declaration of your functions.

Answer (score 3):

```
getLineLength(line, MAXIMUMLINELENGTH)
```

`MAXLINELENGTH` is defined constant

Inside function `getLineLength` is this value "mapped" to `maxLineLength` variable

Answer (score 3):

`maxLineLength` is a parameter/argument for the `getLineLength` function. You are expected to pass in a max length for the line when calling this function.

In the `main` function, it's done here:

```
getLineLength(line, MAXIMUMLINELENGTH)
```

He passes in `MAXIMUMLINELENGTH` as the max line length, which is equal to `1000` as can be seen by this definition in the code:

```
#define MAXIMUMLINELENGTH 1000
```

These `#define`s are specific to the preprocessor. It replaces all instances of `MAXIMUMLINELENGTH` with `1000` before compiling.

Answer (score 2):

The line

```
#define MAXIMUMLINELENGTH 1000
```

is the clue to the puzzle

Answer (score 2):

C source files are pre-processed prior to compilation.

The `#define MAXIMUMLINELENGTH 1000` is a [C preprocessor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_preprocessor) directive that instructs the pre processor to replace all occurrences of the string `MAXIMUMLINELENGTH` with `1000`.

If you use `MAXIMUMLINELENGTH` consistently through out this compilation unit (.C file) and decide at a later time that the line length should change you only have to make the change to pre-preprocessor directive and then that change is reflected through out this compilation unit.

So the line  `getLineLength(line, MAXIMUMLINELENGTH)` is transformed by the preprocessor to  `getLineLength(line, 1000)`