# VS2012 intellisense Icon meaning (Play Icon with vertical lines)

Tags: visual-studio-2012

1) I looked read the article on [microsoft](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y47ychfe%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)'s page where icons are described but I couldn't find the icon **"Play Button with vertical lines"** (it is accentuated with a red line in the image below). What does it mean?

[image: Babel Icon - Intellisense Icons]

2) Further more the **purple Cube** has according to the provided link two meanings:

- Method or Function
- External Declaration

So isn't that confusing?

Comment: Confusing, maybe, an external declaration in C# is a method declaration with a P/Invoke attribute on top of it. For the purpose of calling conventions etc, it's just a Method or Function depending on how you look at it.

Answer (score 1):

It seems to be a "Group Macro" glyph:

[image]

Comment: So i am using C++ and OpenGl library, so what could be the meaning of "GlyphGroupMacro" is this defined by the Programmer? I thought that this icons are appearing autoamtically?

Comment: It is a constant value defined by a macro or preprocessor directive:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3216752/what-is-the-difference-between-macro-constants-and-constant-variables-in-c

Comment: The screen shot is from the Visual Studio see and lists all the icons that ship with intellisense out of the box from the perspective of a developer of a component inside Visual Studio. As such it's one of the most complete sources of icons and their meaning :).