# Visual Studio 2019, XAML what are these properties symbols?

Tags: xaml, mvvm, xamarin.forms, visual-studio-2019

When I'm adding properties to a tag and it shows the dropdown, what do the different symbols mean? I've boxed them in the red square. If you know a good link to learn on how to use/bind each type that be cool.

[image]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23488335/vs2012-intellisense-icon-meaning-play-icon-with-vertical-lines

Comment: Wrench is Property, Lighting is Event, Curly Brace is Namespace, Box is (I think) reserved word or keyword

Comment: Thank you for the help