# C++ - enum vs. const vs. #define

Tags: c++, macros, constants, enumeration

At the end of the article here: http://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/45-enumerated-types/, it mentions the following:

*Finally, as with constant variables, enumerated types show up in the debugger, **making them more useful than #defined values in this regard**.*

How is the bold sentence above achieved?

Thanks.

Comment: I edited the title and added one tag, hope you wouldn't mind. :-)

Comment: @Nawaz. That's totally fine, don't worry about it.

Comment: possible duplicate of ["static const" vs "#define" in c](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1674032/static-const-vs-define-in-c)

Comment: @MatthieuM. Certainly not. The rules of C++ are different enough that it deserves a different answer.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Consider this code,

```
#define WIDTH 300

enum econst
{
   eWidth=300
};

const int Width=300;

struct sample{};

int main() 
{
        sample s;
        int x = eWidth * s; //error 1
        int y = WIDTH * s;  //error 2
        int z = Width * s;  //error 3
        return 0;
}
```

Obviously each multiplication results in compilation-error, **but see how the GCC generates the messages for each multiplication error:**

> prog.cpp:19: error: no match for
>   ‘operator*’ in ‘eWidth * s’
>   prog.cpp:20: error: no match for
>   ‘operator*’ in ‘300 * s’
>   prog.cpp:21: error: no match for
>   ‘operator*’ in ‘Width * s’

In the error message, you don't see the macro `WIDTH` which you've `#defined`, right? That is because by the time GCC makes any attempt to compile the line corresponds to second error, it doesn't see `WIDTH`, all it sees only 300, as before GCC compiles the line, preprocessor has **already** replaced `WIDTH` with 300. On the other hand, there is no any such thing happens with *enum* `eWidth`  and *const* `Width`.

See the error yourself here : http://www.ideone.com/naZ3P

---

Also, read `Item 2 : Prefer consts, enums, and inlines to #defines` from **Effective C++** by Scott Meyers.

Comment: Admittedly, Clang would probably produce a better error message by showing the line that caused the error and thus include the macro (along with its expansion). Though I agree that macros should not be used for constants, I think a better treatment of the question would not use gcc's error messages as the corner stone of the reasoning.

Comment: @MatthieuM.: Clang might produce a better error message, but those who use GCC to compile their code are not going to recompile their code with Clang so as to see a better error message. {contd}

Comment: {contd}...So such reasoning is very much compiler dependent, and therefore I think taking Clang error message as the corner stone of reasoning wouldn't be any better either, because someone might come and say exactly what you said, replacing *"Clang"* with *"GCC, MSVC"*, and *"better"* with *"not-so-better"*, ending his comnent with *"I think a better treatment of the question would not use **Clang**'s error messages as the corner stone of the reasoning"* . Hope you got my point. :-)

Comment: I understand what you are trying to get at, but I disagree. I think that using the compiler error messages as an argument for enums rather than macros is *weak*, in the sense that it depends how the compiler build those error messages, which changes from compiler to compiler and version to version. But then the question itself is rather weird, since it is based on present behavior of debuggers... so I don't care much.

Comment: @MatthieuM.: I don't see any other *better* argument for preferring `const` over `#define`, if this argument is weak. How good (and practical) an argument is, can be said in the light of all other arguments. Compilers behaviors, along the language, determines what one should use. Otherwise, what else decides?

Comment: you mean, apart from the fact that macros are unscoped and untyped, obviously ?

Comment: I know this question is quite old as is this answer but i always had one question about this. Memory usage. Which of the three will result in a variable being created that would take up space in the compiled programm?

Comment: @RedX: Macro (such as `#define X 40`) doesn't take any memory. But ...  please don't worry about that. Even if const variables takes few bytes, use `const` variables. In many cases, compiler can optimize the code, so even const variables can save you memory (if they're really constant). Or use enum, they can save you bytes.

Comment: @Nawaz i develop code for embedded systems, so it is natural for me to worry about the number of global variables and the space they take. I have been searching for quite some time for a way to reduce the use of `#define` but was always worried about the memory usage.

Comment: @RedX: In that case, `enum` should help you in C (or in C++, you can also use constant expression, defined with `const` or `constexpr`). Try them.

Comment: The link mentioned in the post doesn't seem to be going anywhere

Comment: The link is dead "Solution not found"

Comment: Also this is no longer true, a modern version of GCC gives:
`<source>:16:19: error: no match for 'operator*' (operand types are 'int' and 'sample')
   16 |     int y = WIDTH * s;  //error 2`

Answer (score 16):

`enum` is compile time constant with debug info with no storage allocation.

`const` is allocated with a storage, depending on whether it is optimised away by the compiler with constant propagation.

`#define` has no storage allocation.

Comment: `enum` would take storage space whenever a variable of that `enum` type is declared in your program. Isn't it? I believe your mention regarding `enum` is for the case when a variable of that `enum` type is never declared in the program. But why would someone declare an enum and not use it?

Comment: I'd +1 if you could clarify that fact that "no storage allocation" does not mean "doesn't use memory". All of these require the data to be stored somewhere, but the difference between "storage allocation" and "no storage allocation" is where.

Answer (score 6):

`#define` values are replaced by the pre-processor with the value they are declared as, so in the debugger, it only sees the value, not the #defined name, e.g. if you have #define NUMBER_OF_CATS 10, in the debugger you'll see only 10 (since the pre-processor has replaced every instance of NUMBER_OF_CATS in your code with 10.

An enumerated type is a type in itself and the values are constant instances of this type, and so the pre-processor leaves it alone and you'll see the symbolic description of the value in the debugger.

Answer (score 3):

The compiler stores enum information in the binary when the program is compiled with certain options.

When a variable is of a enum type, a debugger can show the enum name. This is best shown with an example:

```
enum E {
    ONE_E = 1,
};

int main(void)
{
    enum E e = 1;

    return 0;
}
```

If you compile that with `gcc -g` you can try out the following in `gdb`:

```
Reading symbols from test...done.
(gdb) b main
Breakpoint 1 at 0x804839a: file test.c, line 8.
(gdb) run
Starting program: test 

Breakpoint 1, main () at test.c:7
7               enum E e = 1;
(gdb) next
9               return 0;
(gdb) print e
$1 = ONE_E
(gdb)
```

If you used a define, you would not have a proper type to give `e`, and would have to use an integer. In that case, the compiler would print `1` instead of `ONE_E`.

The `-g` flag asks gdb to add debugging information to the binary. You can even see that it is there by issuing:

```
xxd test | grep ONE_E
```

I don't think that this will work in all architectures, though.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. What do you mean by: "The compiler stores enum information in the binary"? Thanks.

Comment: Literally, the binary has that information in it in a format that gdb understands.From the gcc manual: -g Produce debugging information in the operating system's native format (...).  GDB can work with this debugging information.

Answer (score 1):

At least for Visual Studio 2008 which I currently have at hand, this sentence is correct. If you have

```
#define X 3
enum MyEnum
{
    MyX = 3
};

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    int i = X;
    int j = (int)MyX;
    return 0;
}
```

and you set a breakpont in `main`, you can hover your mouse over "MyX" and see that it evaluates to 3. You do not see anything useful if you hover over X.

But this is not a language property but rather IDE behavior. Next versions might do it differently, as well as others IDEs. So just check it out for your IDE to see if this sentence applies in your case.

Comment: It **is** a language property, in that `X` is not even seen by the compiler (only the preprocessed value `3`), therefore the debugger has absolutely no way of using `X` as a symbolic name, thus it will show you only the plain value `3`. This is true of all compilers and IDEs. OTOH showing symbols like `MyX` in the debugger is indeed an IDE-specific feature, but it is so common I doubt there is any modern IDE which does not offer this.

Comment: @PéterTörök There's nothing to stop someone creating a compiler that also does preprocessing or creating a way of placing `X` in the symbol table.

Answer (score 0):

I am answering too late but i feel i can add something -
enum vs. const vs. #define

**enum** -

1. Does not require assining values (if just want to have sequential values 0, 1, 2..) whereas in case of #defines you manually need to manage values which could cause human error sometime
2. It works just as variable to during online debugging the value of enum can be watched in watch window
3. You can have a variable of enum type to which you can assign an enum

   typedef enum numbers
   {
     DFAULT,
     CASE_TRUE,
     CASE_OTHER,
   };

   int main(void)
   {
     numbers number = CASE_TRUE;
   }

**const** -

1. It is constant stored in read only area of memory but can be accessed using address which is not possible in case of #define

   1. You have type check in your hand if you use const rather than #define
2. defines are pre-processing directive but const is compile time
   for example

   const char *name = "vikas";

You can access the name and use its base address to read the such as vikas[3] to read 'a' etc.

**#defines** -
are dumb preprocessor directives which does textual replacement

Answer (score 0):

Check the following article, nice summary 
http://www.queryhome.com/26340/define-vs-enum-vs-constant