# #define and CUDA

Tags: c++, cuda, c-preprocessor

Why does the following snippet not work with CUDA (both 3.2 and 4.0)?

```
#define NUM_BLOCKS 16

// lots of code.

dim3 dimBlock(NUM_BLOCKS, NUM_BLOCKS);
```

but this,

```
dim3 dimBlock(16, 16);
```

does?

I keep getting a `error : expected a ")"` and `error : expected an expression`. What am I missing?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Are you certain you didn't write

```
#define NUM_BLOCKS 16;
```

(note the semicolon at the end)?

I get exactly the errors you described, when the erroneus semicolon is there.

Comment: Hell, that was it! I was scrolling through pages and pages of preprocessed code, only to be laid low by a semicolon! Me > doofus.

Comment: @Kristian: See...As I said if you had used `const int` or `enum` instead of `#define`, you wouldn't have faced this problem :D

Answer (score 2):

That is strange. It may be because of the usual problem with macros. If you know, macros don't respect scope. It may be that the same macro is defined elsewhere, but differently.

Why don't you use `const int` or `enum` instead of macro?

Do you know this: [C++ - enum vs. const vs. #define](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4767667/c-enum-vs-const-vs-define) ??

Comment: Yeah, but in principle at least it should work, which is why I find it strange.

Comment: @Kristian: As I said, if there is the usual problem, then how will it work? Making sure that the problem doesn't exist, is difficult with macros, that is why `const int` or `enum` is preferred.

Comment: What do you mean Nawaz? I tried renaming the macro to an obviously user-created one. I don't see why it shouldn't work. Anyway, I'll try and get to the bottom of this later today...

Answer (score 1):

One way to find out is to get your compiler driver to stop after the preprocessing stage so that you can see what has been generated. This will show you what the preprocessor substituted and therefore gives you something to search for.

The option is -E if you are using gcc and /E for MSVC.

For the nvcc compiler driver a typical command would be

```
nvcc -E file.cu -o file.cup
```

Comment: I suspect it's something to do with how NVCC sees preprocessor commands, since this is a `.cu` file?

Comment: @Kristian D'Amato: I'm not familiar with CUDA but I just had a quick look at the nvcc manual and it says it supports the `-E` option to generate preprocessed source from a .cu file. I'll edit my answer with a sample command line.