# Priority of #define vs. const declaration

Tags: c++, variables, constants, c-preprocessor, overwrite

can a `#define` "overwrite" a const variable or vice versa? Or will it lead to a compiler error?

```
//ONE
#define FOO 23
const int FOO = 42;

//TWO
const int FOO = 42;
#define FOO 23
```

What value will FOO have in both cases, 42 or 23?

Comment: Easiest way to think of `#define` is as just a Find+Replace search on every line after you `#define` something.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First one will give compilation error. Macros are visible from the point of their definition.

That is, first one is equivalent to:

```
//ONE
#define FOO 23
const int 23= 42; //which would cause compilation error
```

And second one is this:

```
//TWO
const int FOO = 42;
#define FOO 23 //if you use FOO AFTER this line, it will be replaced by 23
```

Since macros are dumb, in C++ `const` and `enum` are preferred over macros. See my answer  here in which I explained why macros are bad, and `const` and `enum` are better choices.

- [C++ - enum vs. const vs. #define](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4767667/c-enum-vs-const-vs-define)