# C++ / Qt Coding style - where should a #define go

Tags: c++, qt, constants, qgraphicsitem

I am trying to build a break-out game clone in `Qt`. I need to figure out what type of a `QGraphicsItem` my ball collided with. For example if I the ball collides with the wall, the ball just bounces off, if it collides with a brick it has to bounce off and destroys the brick. To find out what kind of `QGraphicsItem` it is, I figured the best way to do that is probably to override `QGraphicsItem::type()` (Please let me know if this is not the right way!).

In the following code for `brick.h` I set my 'Brick' to have a Type of 3. Now, the value 3 looks really cumbersome to track. I would instead prefer to declare something with a '#define'

```
#include <QGraphicsItem>

//should this #define be here?
//#define BRICK_SPRITE 3

class Brick : public QGraphicsItem
{
public:
    Brick(const QPixmap& p, QGraphicsScene *scene = 0);
    virtual QRectF boundingRect() const;
    virtual void paint( QPainter *painter,
                        const QStyleOptionGraphicsItem *option,
                        QWidget *widget );

    QPainterPath shape() const;

    enum { Type = 3 }; //enum {Type = BRICK_SPRITE}

    int type() const { return Type; }

private:
    QPixmap pixmap;
};
```

Where is a good location to place the statement '#define BRICK_SPRITE 3' ? I have several other files in the project. Should I place all the definitions in a separate header file?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Why not just use `Type` instead of 3?  `enum`s in c++ are implicitly convertible to `int`

If you *really* wanted a new name instead, I suggest you use a `const int` variable instead of a `#define` -- it is type and namespace safe, while preprocessor macros aren't.

Something like:

```
class Brick : public QGraphicsItem
{
  static const int BRICK_SPRITE = 3;
  // rest of the class definition
};
```

According to the documentations I could find, the approach you are taking with the enum and overriding `type()` is indeed the preferred way

Comment: The enum hack should no longer be needed for decent compilers, the inline static const int is the best way.

Comment: @Atilla - I am not sure if I understood your statement 'Why not just use Type instead of 3' . If I use enum { Type}; , Type would automatically be 0. Is this what you meant? I want the value of Type to be 3. There is no particular reason for that. I guess my reason is I want it to be unique.

Comment: No, I meant to keep the enum defintion as you have now and use `Type` when you would want to use `BRICK_SPRITE` -- if the name `Type` is not expressive enough for you, you can change it to `BRICK_TYPE` in the enum, or define a named constant as suggested in my answer

Answer (score 5):

If you want to follow Qt's conventions, you can start by not naming your constants in all caps...they don't do that.  Also, using preprocessor macros for constants is not idiomatic C++, as @Atilla points out.  There are lots of good reasons, like being able to see the value in the debugger:

[C++ - enum vs. const vs. #define](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4767667/c-enum-vs-const-vs-define)

It's usually the case that you can find a class which it makes sense to "own" constants.  When Qt doesn't really have a place to put it, it just puts things in the namespace `Qt::`

http://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-4.7/qt.html

So if you find it doesn't make sense for `Brick` to own this value, you can have a namespace in your program where you put such things.

I actually didn't know `QGraphicsItem::type()` was a standard thing...hadn't come across it.  You've noticed [in the documentation](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qgraphicsitem.html#type) that it says custom user types should start at `UserType + 1`...so I'd definitely follow that rule.  It says you only need to do this if you plan on using `qgraphicsitem_cast()`, so maybe the examples I've looked at just didn't need it.

The only unusual thing Qt brings to the table (that I can think of) in terms of conventions for declaring constants is something called Q_DECLARE_FLAGS, which brings type-safety in cases where you OR together flags:

http://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-4.7/qflags.html

So if you were doing something like:

```
class Brick : public QGraphicsItem {
public:
    static const int Type = UserType + 1;
    enum BrickFlag {
        DamagesBall = 0x1,
        ContainsCoins = 0x2,
        MultipleHits = 0x4
    };
    Q_DECLARE_FLAGS(BrickFlags, BrickFlag)
}

Q_DECLARE_OPERATORS_FOR_FLAGS(Brick::BrickFlags)
```

Now you have a special safe type called `Brick::BrickFlags`, that cannot (for instance) be OR'd together with `Brick::Type`.

Comment: Following your advise and Attila's, I am going to change the declaration to static const int. By the way I saw a line in Qt documententation enum { Type = UserType + 1 }; UserType in QGraphicsItem is 65536. I wonder if I should follow this instead of assigning a value 3 (which I believe will be unique in my application). If I use UserType+1 for brick, I guess I will have to have a line static const int BrickSprite  = UserType + 1;

Comment: Ah.  I didn't know type() was a standard thing.  Updated my answer to reflect this.