# Simple error in C language

Tags: c, arrays, constants

```
const int size = 10; // realna ilość danych
int tablica[size+1];
```

i have:
**variable-size type declared outside of any function**

Comment: If you want to have size set during compilation, it would suffice to write "#define size 10"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use

```
#define size 10
```

instead of a `const int`. The latter is not a compile-time constant in C, but a variable that cannot be assigned to (unless via a pointer and a cast to get rid of `const`).

(This is a difference between C and C++.)

Answer (score 3):

You could use an enum.

```
enum
{
    size = 10
};

int table[size + 1];
```

Answer (score 3):

Use:

```
enum { size = 10 };
```

This is a constant value that can be used in declarations and in case labels and so on.  In C99, inside a function, the original code would not be a problem -- your array `tablica` would be a VLA or variable-length array (and the compiler error message is trying to say "you can't have a VLA outside a function").

Using an enum gives better traceability when you use a debugger on your code; the symbol is included in the symbol table.  Typically, C preprocessor symbols are not available to the debugger, so trying to print 'size' when it is #define'd doesn't print an answer; printing 'size' when it is an enum does.

See also: ["static const" vs "#define" in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1674032/static-const-vs-define-in-c)

Comment: I knew there was definitely some good reasons to use an enum over a #define ;-) just couldn't recall what they were.

Answer (score 1):

The error is fairly self-explanatory. You can't declare a variable-length array outside of a function. Although the size of the array you're creating is, in practice, fixed at compile time, you've still technically violated the constraints of the language.

The usual choices are:

1. Move the array into a function. (Usually the best option, remember globals are to be avoided when possible.)
2. `#define size n` where `n` is the size you want, instead of using an int. (Usually better than "magic numbers", and pretty standard practice in traditional C.)
3. Use a "magic number" (`int tablica[11];`). (Usually the last choice, though sometimes it does make more sense.)