# defining #ifdef at runtime

Tags: c, runtime, conditional-compilation

I am trying to use #ifdef preprocessive directive in my program.
I want to define this macro at run time (would be better if I define this value in another configuration file so that I can define it or undefine it any time without compiling)  and so I don't want to define it in make file.

I searched a lot about this in Google. But I am not able to get the exact information which I wanted.

Is there any way to define it in run time.?
If yes, kindly suggest.

Comment: "Preprocessor" means it runs before the source code is processed by the compiler. So if I understand correctly what you want it is a completely nonsense. Like running program before it is programmed and compiled? Not possible.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Changing a macro at runtime in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7572872/changing-a-macro-at-runtime-in-c)

Answer (score 6):

No, `#ifdef` and other `#` directives are used during compilation only, and in fact even before the compilation itself by an (internal) tool called the *preprocessor*.

If you want run-time configurability, you will need to use plain `if` statements etc. Or make two builds of the same program etc.