# Redefining a #define in c++ on run time

Tags: c++, embedded

Right now I'm merging two codes with the same core, but they differentiate with the #defines, what I need is to make a way around it an choose wicth configuration I need on run time, the code uses if ENABLE(defined) to verify the configurations to load, how can I modify the code to make it work?
Thanks

Comment: You can't. By the time the compiler starts compiling your code, there is no trace of `#define`s and other preprocessor directives left in the source. You need to figure out some other strategy.

Comment: Teeeeeechnically, some levels of debugging symbols let you keep them to enable a better debugging experience :)

Comment: Is it better to declare them as variables and change the dependencies that uses this #defines? But for example, there are a lot of vector using them to declare their size, and I can't simple declare a vector size with a int like vector [int]...

Comment: @AlessandroQueiroz, Vector sizes can be runtime values. Did you mean arrays?

Comment: I would suggest you rephrase your question. :-) The way you've phrased it already has an answer, and the answer is "You can't.". Perhaps a more detailed explanation of what you ultimately want to accomplish instead of asking how to make a particular idea you had for accomplishing it work?

Comment: @chris, yes an array, sorry...

Answer (score 2):

You can't. Macro are pre-processor. They are gone during compilation.
Variables are the best choice.
By the way, this question is answered here.

[Changing a macro at runtime in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7572872/changing-a-macro-at-runtime-in-c)