# How to set dynamically toggle defined macro?

Tags: c

Im trying to make my defines can be switched during runtime, so I cant enable/disable printing some info.

I have next files:

- main.c
- config.c
- config.h (included in both c files)

in config.c :

```c
//define DEBUG   // <--------------- COMMENT THIS TO SWITCH PRINT/NOT PRINT

#define PRINTF(fmt, ...)    printf("TAG: " fmt "\n", ## __VA_ARGS__)

#ifdef  DEBUG
#define DPRINTF PRINTF
#else
#define DPRINTF(...)    do {} while (0)
#endif

int foo()
{
   ...
   if(error){
      PRINTF("error happens, code %d", code);
   }
   else{
      DPRINF("all good, all parameters: [%d][%d]", par1, par2);
   }
}
```

(short explanation: if `DEBUG` defined then macro **D**PRINTF will print some info, otherwise do nothing)

What I want is be able to dynamically switch it from main.c somehow, instead of comment / uncomment and recompile program.

So my idea was to set in config.h

```c
extern  uint8_t dbg_status;
#define DGB_ON  (1)
#define DGB_OFF (0)
#define ENABLE_DBG (dbg_status? (DGB_ON) : (DGB_OFF))
```

And in main.c do something like that:

```c
uint8_t dbg_status;

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    // enable debug if run with next argument:
    // program.exe -DEBUG 
    if (!strcmp(argv[1], "-DEBUG"))
    {
        // enable debug prints
        dbg_status= 1;
    }
    else
    {
        // disable debug prints
        dbg_status= 0;
    }
    ...
}
```

But Im stuck with it now, I dont know what to do next...

Add some additional defines in config.c?

```
#if (ENABLE_DEBUG)
#define DEBUG
#endif
```

I feel that Im on right way, but dont see where to move next.

**UPD:**
Original idea from here:
[Changing a macro at runtime in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7572872/changing-a-macro-at-runtime-in-c)

But Im stuck with realization...

Comment: Macros are not present at run time. They control / are used during compilation.

Comment: Macros are expanded when compiling. If you want it to be conditional on a runtime value, it needs to expand into an `if` statement.

Answer (score 0):

You could use something like this:

```
int debugflag = 0;
void DPRINTF(char *format, ...) {
        if (!debugflag)
                return;
        va_list ap;
        va_start(ap, format);
        vfprintf(stderr, format, ap);
        va_end(ap);
}
```

Now you can choose dynamically with the global variable `debugflag` if you want the debug output or not.

With macros, this is not possible directly, since these are evaluated at compile time and cannot be influenced at runtime directly.

Comment: Any ways to use DPRINTF with my old prototypes of macro?
Its just too many places to edit...

so another exampe of this:

`PRINTF("%s(%d): failed loading file to buffer", __func__, __LINE__);`



Can I use your function with same arguments in my code?

Comment: Yes, it looks like you could just rename it to `DPRINTF`

Comment: Hmm, its says **uninitialized local variable 'ap' used**