# How to decide when n should be a const object or a symbolic constant (macro)?

Tags: c

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [“static const” vs “#define” in c](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1674032/static-const-vs-define-in-c)

I am going through the K&R book and this question came up. How to best decide whether something should be its own variable or be defined as a symbolic constant?

Suppose we're dealing with `const int myNumber = 12;` , which also can be `#define MY_NUMBER 12` is there a rule of thumb one should follow when deciding which whether a variable needs to be created or symbolic constant used?

Comment: See [static const vs #define](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1674032/static-const-vs-define-in-c/), which also discusses `enum` as a frequently useful alternative.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're hard-coding a constant like "2" ... then it's a candidate for symbolic parameter.

ADDENDUM:

You changed the question :)

> Q: I am going through the K&R book and this question came up. How to
>   best decide whether something should be its own variable or be defined
>   as a symbolic parameter?

A: "Magic numbers" are bad.  Use "#define SOME_MEANINGFUL_NAME 2" in preference to "2".

> Q: Suppose were dealing with const int myNumber = 12; , which also can
>   be #define MY_NUMBER 12 is there a rule of thumb one should follow
>   when deciding which approach to take here?

A: If you're using C++ or C#, then you should probably use "const" in favor of "#define".

Answer (score 7):

The real question is whether `n` should be a declared `const` object or a macro.  (The question's title currently refers to "a variable or a symbolic constant".)

This:

```
const int myNumber = 12;
```

makes `myNumber` `const` but not *constant*.  The `const` keyword means that you're not allowed to modify the object it applies to, but it doesn't make it *constant*.  Switch labels, for example, must be constant; you can't write:

```
switch (n) {
    case myNumber:
    ...
}
```

So if you need to use `myNumber` in a context that requires a constant expression, the above isn't going to work.

On the other hand, a macro:

```
#define MY_NUMBER 12
```

means that any use of `MY_NUMBER` is replaced by a literal `12`, which is constant.  A drawback of macros is that they're not scoped the way declared objects are; the name `MY_NUMBER` is visible from the definition to the end of the source file, which can cause conflicts.  (Note that macro names are conventionally written in all-caps, specifically to draw attention to them.)  In effect, the preprocessor, which is where macros are handled is another language tacked onto C.

For constants of type `int`, there's another trick you can use (I don't think K&R mention this):

```
enum { myNumber = 12 };
```

This creates an anonymous enumeration type, which you aren't actually going to use.  `myNumber` is actually of type `int`, not of the enumeration type, and you can use it the same way you'd use the literal `12`.  You can even use an expression to define its value, as long as the expression is constant:

```
enum { myNumber = 3 * 4 };
```

(C++ has different rules.  In C++, `const int myNumber = 12;` does make `myNumber` a constant expression -- and enumeration constants are of the enumerated type, not of type `int`.)