# What are the major advantages of const versus #define for global constants?

Tags: c++, c

In embedded programming, for example, `#define GLOBAL_CONSTANT 42` is preferred to `const int GLOBAL_CONSTANT = 42;` for the following reasons:

- it does not need place in RAM (which is usually very limited in microcontrollers, and µC applications usually need a large number of global constants)
- `const` needs not only a storage place in the flash, but the compiler generates extra code at the start of the program to copy it.

Against all these advantages of using `#define`, what are the major advantages of using `const`?
In a non-µC environment memory is usually not such a big issue, and `const` is useful because it can be used locally, but what about global constants? Or is the answer just "we should never ever ever use global constants"?

**Edit:**

The examples might have caused some misunderstanding, so I have to state that they are in C. If the C compiler generated the exact same code for the two, I think that would be an error, not an optimization.

I just extended the question to C++ without thinking much about it, in the hopes of getting new insights, but it was clear to me, that in an object-oriented environment there is very little space for global constants, regardless whether they are macros or consts.

Comment: Is this for C or C++ because `const` in C++ has different semantics to `const` in C

Comment: "it does not need place in RAM" It's been a while since I looked at assembly, but I figured a compiler would be smart enough to do whatever it wanted with a `const int`. Unless you actually take the address of `GLOBAL_CONSTANT`, there's nothing that prevents the compiler from optimizing the variable away. As for "the compiler generates extra code at the start of the program to copy it," that would have to be a pretty terrible compiler.

Comment: You might want to check these:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1637332/static-const-vs-define
and
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1674032/static-const-vs-define-in-c

Comment: Recently asked [const-value-vs-define-which-kind-of-chip-resource-will-be-used](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9833514) Is this a homework? I ask because it is so similar.

Comment: @NicolBolas, if the const is not static, it needs to be addressable, so other program units (files) can refer to it. To avoid memory allocation, the use of static is recommended. Of course, the compiler may opt to not optimize that...

Comment: @guga: "it needs to be addressable, so other program units (files) can refer to it." But it's the same in all of them. If you've declared it in a header as `const`, every use of them must refer to *exactly the same* value. Therefore, unless you actually take the address of it, the compiler is totally free to replace the variable access with a value.

Comment: @NicolBolas, nope, you can have extern const variable without declaring its value.

Comment: @guga: Then *those* translation units will have to access memory to get the variable. The translation units where the `const` variable is fully defined *do not*.

Comment: @NicolBolas, so if file A has it as non static, and file B has it as extern, how the compiler will optimize file A without knowing about file B?

Comment: @guga: How would it not? I don't understand your question. When compiling the file, it checks to see if it was a definition or a declaration (`extern`). If it's a definition, then it can replace it. If it's a declaration, it can't. It's *that simple*.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/9498/discussion-between-guga-and-nicol-bolas)

Comment: @guga: nothing prevents the compiler from doing link-time code generation and link-time code optimization.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer to your question varies for C and C++.

In C, `const int GLOBAL_CONSTANT` is not a *constant* in C, So the primary way to define a true constant in C is by using `#define`.

In C++, One of the major advantage of using `const` over `#define` is that `#defines` don't respect scopes so there is no way to create a class scoped namespace. While const variables can be scoped in classes.

Apart from that there are other subtle advantages like:

**Avoiding Weird magical numbers during compilation errors:**

If you are using `#define` those are replaced by the pre-processor at time of precompilation So if you receive an error during compilation, it will be confusing because the error message wont refer the macro name but the value and it will appear a sudden value, and one would waste lot of time tracking it down in code.

**Ease of Debugging:**

Also for same reasons mentioned in #2, while debugging `#define` would provide no help really.

Comment: Just a clarification: what is that "#2" you are referring to?

Comment: @vsz: `#1`== *Point on what const means in c* `#2` == *Avoiding Weird magical numbers during compilation errors*

Comment: So that means, in C there can be a few reasons to use macro instead of const, but in C++ there is absolutely no advantage in using macros only to define constants. You could add this to your answer if that was what you meant.

Answer (score 8):

Are you sure your compiler is too dumb to optimize your constant by inserting its value where it is needed instead of putting it into memory? Compilers usually are good in optimizations.

And the main advantage of constants versus macros is that constants have scope. Macros are substituted everywhere with no respect for scope or context. And it leads to really hard to understand compiler error messages.
Also debuggers are not aware of macros.
More can be found [here](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/newbie.html#faq-29.7)

Answer (score 3):

Another reason that hasn't been mentioned yet is that `const` variables allow the compiler to perform explicit type-checking, but macros do not.  Using `const` can help prevent subtle data-dependent errors that are often difficult to debug.

Answer (score 1):

I think the main advantage is that you can change the constant without having to recompile everything that uses it.

Since a macro change will effectively modify the contents of the file that use the macro, recompilation is necessary.

Comment: I guess you're referring to situation where the constant is only declared in a header file and defined somewhere else? But it's not really a compile time constant anymore.

Answer (score 1):

In C the `const` qualifier does not define a constant but instead a read-only object:

```
#define A  42       // A is a constant
const int a = 42;  // a is not constant
```

A `const` object cannot be used where a real constant is required, for example:

```
static int bla1 = A;  // OK, A is a constant
static int bla2 = a;  // compile error, a is not a constant
```

Note that this is different in C++ where the `const` really qualifies an object as a constant.

Answer (score 1):

The only problems you list with `const` sum up as "I've got the most incompetent compiler I can possibly imagine". The problems with `#define`, however, are universal- for example, no scoping.

Answer (score 1):

There's no reason to use `#define` instead of a `const int` in C++.  Any decent C++ compiler will substitute the constant value from a const int in the same way it does for a #define where it is possible to do so.  Both take approximately the same amount of flash when used the same way.

Using a `const` does allow you to take the address of the value (where a macro does not).  At that point, the behavior obviously diverges from the behavior of a Macro.  The const now needs a space in the program in both flash and in RAM to live so that it can have an address.  But this is really what you want.

The overhead here is typically going to be an extra 8 bytes, which is tiny compared to the size of most programs.   Before you get to this level of optimization, make sure you have exhausted all other options like compiler flags.  Using the compiler to carefully optimize for size and not using things like `template`s in C++ will save you a lot more than 8 bytes.