# manifest constants vs C++ keyword "const"

Tags: c++

Reading the book of Meyers (item 2 "Prefer const to #define) I'd like to understand some sentences that I list below:

1. With reference to the comparison between `#define ASPECT_RATIO 1.653` and `const aspect_ratio = 1.653` Meyers asks that "... in the case of floating point constant (such as in this example) use of the constant may yield smaller code than using `#define`." 
   The questions are: 
   With smaller code Meyers means the a smaller space on disk of executable file?
   Why it is smaller? I thought that this may be valid on system with 32 bit because in this case an `int` (or pointer) needs 4 bytes and a double 8 bytes. Because `ASPECT_RATIO` may not get entered into symbol table the name is replaced with the value, while in other cases may be used a `const` pointer to a unique double value. In this case this concept would no longer be valid on machines with 64 bit (because pointer and double are the same number of bytes). I do not know if I explained well what I mean, and especially if this idea is correct?
2. Then Meyers asks that " ...though good compilers won't set aside storage for `const` objects of integral types (unless you create a pointer or reference to the object) sloppy compilers may, and you may not be willing to set aside memory for such objects..."
   In this context the memory is the RAM occupied by the process in execution? If it is correct to verify this I can use task manager (in Win) or top (in Linux)?

Comment: have a read through [this almost duplicate post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9941107/what-are-the-major-advantages-of-const-versus-define-for-global-constants?rq=1)

Comment: Thanks for the reference, in part, the question is similar but the answers do not help me to clarify my doubts

Comment: I am taking out the C tag, since you seem to be mainly interested in C++. C and C++ are very different with respect to that, in particular with the additions of C++11 (`constepr`).

Answer (score 7):

First, micro-optimizations are stupid. Don't care about a couple of constant double values eating up all your RAM. It won't happen. If it does, handle it then, not before you know it's even relevant.

Second, `#define` can have nasty side effects if used too much, even with the `ALL_CAPS_DEFINES` convention. Sooner or later you're going to mistakenly make a short macro that is used in some other variable's name, with preprocessor replacement giving you an unfathomable and avoidable error and no debuggability at all. As the linked question in the question comments states, macro's lack namespace and class scope, and are definitely bad in C++.

Third, C++11 adds `constexpr`, which allows typesafe macro-performant (whatever this misnomer should mean) constant expressions. There are even those (see the C++ Lounge in SO Chat) that do whole calculations at compile time using `constexpr`. Unfortunately, not all major compilers claiming C++11 support, actually support enough C++11 features to be truly useful (I'm looking at you, MSVC2012!).

Comment: Thanks for the reply. My goal is not optimization but only understand the meaning of the phrases that I pointed out

Comment: @GTA the quotes seem to me like a misplaced reason to base the decision of one over the other on final memory use. Sure, the compiler *might* optimize it out, it might not. It might even be faster in some cases to not optimize out the constant variable (think cache misses etc.). The difference will be hardly noticable for an optimized build, I reckon, and I doubt for the case of a single variable you will be able to see the difference in a process manager. Bottom line: use `constexpr` if available, `const` otherwise. If in C, well, ask somebody else, cause I don't use C `:-)`.

Comment: "micro-optimizations are stupid." This doesn't hold true for many 8-bit microcontrollers. I recently put a device on Amazon ("Computa Pranksta") for instance, where I had to get 8kB of program data to fit on ~6kB of flash space, all with 512 bytes of RAM. Not only were micro-optimizations not stupid in this case, but they made the difference between getting the product on Amazon and having to do a complete hardware redesign. I have bytes, literally, a handful of single bytes, remaining in the flash memory for program storage. Just made it. Don't blow off the value of saving 2 bytes.

Answer (score 2):

1. The reason that it "may" yield smaller code is that multiple uses of a define will probably (probably: optimizers do weird stuff) also generate the same constant again and again.  Whereas using a const will only generate one definition, and then reference the same definition (if the optimizer doesn't calculate stuff inline).
2. The linker outputs several parts when linking your executable.  Some part contains constants, some other part executable code.  Wether or not your (operating) system loads the executable into ram before executing, is not defined within the C++ standard.  I've used systems where the code executes from flash storage, so only the stack and dynamically allocated memory uses ram.

Comment: Thanks for your answer in question was not specified but you understand what I meant a multiple use of the variable (ASPECT_RATIO) in code. Because a reference is realized by means a pointer the concept ("the may smaller code") is correct on system with 32bit because with 64 bit pointer and double have the same dimension

Comment: @GTA The generated code doesn't need 32 bits to refer to the const: there are instructions that refer to constants in relative position to the PC (program counter). If you want to find out what your compiler really generates, you should have a look at gcc & objdump, and try out the difference.