# Output of a C program

Tags: c, c-preprocessor

I have written the following C program. The output is 32. Why is this?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define max 10+2

int main(){
    int i;
    i = max * max;
    printf("\n%d\n",i);

    return 0;
}
```

(I am learning C and am relatively new to it.)

Comment: Does it help if I tell you that what the compiler actually sees is "`i=10+2*10+2;`"?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
#define max 10+2
```

This is the preprocessor. it is not smart.

it is stupid.

it just replaces text.

```
max*max
```

will resolve to

```
10+2*10+2
```

which is

```
10+(2*10)+2
```

because of operator precedence, which is

```
10 + 20 + 2
```

i.e. `32`

<s>Furthermore, you should avoid preprocessor macros whenever you can and use `static const` instead</s>. You may or may not want to also consider using a `const` variable or an `enum` instead of a `#define`; each have their tradeoffs, refer to the similar question: ["static const" vs "#define" vs "enum"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1674032/static-const-vs-define-in-c).

If you want to stick to preprocessor, then you could just use:

```
#define max (10+2)
```

Since parenthesised code will take operator precendence.

Comment: Final line is bad advice. In C, a `static const` variable is worse (as a constant) than a preprocessor macro in every single way. The problem is easily solved by adding the correct parentheses to the macro.

Comment: @R.. can you please explain why it is worse.

Comment: The bigges one is that it's not a constant expression, so it can't be used in contexts where a constant expression is required - not even as an initializer for other `static const` objects.

Comment: It is not worse than a macro in every single way, there are plenty of cases where it is better than a macro. Perhaps you want to keep track over how much memory all your const data consumes. Or perhaps you want to keep all const that in a particular segment of ROM. static const is also type safe, #define:d literals are not, they are always (signed) int. And a static const does not needlessly clutter down the global namespace. If "max" in this post isn't going to be used as an initializer, I think it would be better off declared as static const.

Answer (score 2):

Since `max` is a macro, it gets expanded textually, so your code comes out with:

```
i = 10 +2 * 10 + 2;
```

For a macro like this, you generally want to add parentheses:

```
#define max (10+2)
```

So your expression will expand to:

```
i = (10+2) * (10+2);
```

Answer (score 1):

The compiler sees this

```
i = 10 + 2*10 +2 = 32
```

You should do the macro definition like this

```
#define max (10+2)
```

Answer (score 0):

Operator precedence is a funny thing. PEMDAS = Parenthises, Exponents, Multiply, Divide, Add, Subtract.

This is going to resolve to equal to 10 + (2 * 10) + 2.
First is 10*2 which equals 20.

Now it reads 10 + 20 + 2.
The rest should be clear.

You should exercise control over your arithmetics whenever desired.

Comment: PEMDAS doesn't really apply in C. For example, `3<<1+2` yields 24, rather than 8.

Comment: Indeed, forget about PEMDAS, it will do you no good in C. Take this obscure but valid example `a *= --++b / c;`. Subtract, then add, then divide, then multiply.