# #Define VS Variable

Tags: c, variables, c-preprocessor

I cannot understand what is the difference between:

```
#define WIDTH 10
```

and

```
int width = 10;
```

What are the benefits of using the first or the second?

Comment: Read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1674032/static-const-vs-define-in-c) question too

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Well, there is a great difference. You can change the value of `width`, you can take its address, you can ask for its size and so on. With `WIDTH`, it will be just replaced with a constant `10` everywhere, so the expression `++WIDTH` doesn't make any sense. Ono the other side, you can declare an array with `WIDTH` items, whereas you cannot declare an array with `width` items.

Summing it up: the value of `WIDTH` is known at compile time and cannot be changed. The compiler doesn't allocate memory for `WIDTH`. On the contrary, `width` is a variable with *initial* value 10, its further values are not known at compile time; the variable gets its memory from the compiler.

Comment: so the macro WIDTH cannot be changed and it is used to state something "classic" in the program?Like #define AUTHOR "Myself" ??

Comment: @Nick: the macros can be used in thousands of different ways. You can define macro to contain a piece of code: `#define CHECKSUCCESS(n) if (n) return n; else {}`. The way you propose is a valid usage as well.

Comment: @Nick: By the way, with macros you can do weird things, like `#define sin(x) cos(x)`! Use with care.

Answer (score 8):

> **What is the difference between two?**

The first is an **[Macro](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Macros.html)** while second is an Variable declaration.

`#define WIDTH 10` is a **[preprocessor directive](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_preprocessor)** that allows you to specify a name(`WIDTH`) and its replacement text(`10`). The preprocessor parses the source file and each occurrence of the name is replaced by its associated text. The compiler never actually sees a macro name at all, what it sees is the replaced text.

The variable declaration is evaluated by the compiler itself. It tells the compiler to declare a variable named `width` and of the type `int` and also initializes it with a value `10`.
The compiler knows this variable by its own name `width`.

> **Which one should you prefer? And Why?**

Usually, it is recommended to use compile time constant variables over `#define`.
So Your variable declaration should be:

```
const int width = 10;
```

There are a number of reasons for selecting compile time constants over `#define`, namely:

***Scope Based Mechanism:***

The scope of `#define` is limited to the file in which it is defined. So, `#defines` which are created in one source file are **NOT** available in a different source file. In short, `#define`s don't respect scopes.Note that `const` variables can be scoped.They obey all scoping rules.

---

***Avoiding Weird magical numbers during compilation errors:***

If you are using `#define` those are replaced by the pre-processor at time of precompilation So if you receive an error during compilation, it will be confusing because the error message wont refer the macro name but the value and it will appear a sudden  value, and one would waste lot of time tracking it down in code.

---

***Ease of Debugging:***

Also for same reasons mentioned in #2, while debugging `#define` would provide no help really.

Comment: The question is tagged `c`, are you sure about namespaces and classes?

Comment: One advantage of a DEFINE when programming in embedded systems is that a DEFINE will never consume memory where a variable will have to be stored somewhere.

Comment: I thought namespaces and classes are used in C++ .Nice answer though

Comment: @RedX: well, _theoretically_ the variable which is never modified ought to be optimized by the compiler to take no memory. But the embedded compilers are known to be quite weak in optimizations.

Comment: Ahm, Modified the answer to sit the C tag.I didn't see the tags before.

Comment: @Vlad because of the very simple optimizations done by most embedded compilers i thought i'd specifically point that out.

Comment: I'd argue that pre-processing directives also are a bit safer than variables. Considering that you don't apply any obfuscation method, variables are identifiers, suppose `apiKey`, that is human-readable, while the pre-processing directives will replace the reference directly, so it's a bit harder to search for.

Answer (score 2):

`WIDTH` is a macro which will be replaced with the value (10) by the [preprocessor](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/index.html) whereas `width` is a variable.

When you #define a macro (like WIDTH here), the preprocessor will simply do a *text-replacement* before the program is passed to the compiler. i.e. wherever you used `WIDTH` in your code, it'll simply be replaced with `10`.

But when you do `int width=10`, the variable is alive

Comment: still don't getting it.Could you explain it better?

Comment: @Nick I hope you are new to C programming, I would rather suggest you to go through the book.

Comment: `WIDTH` is a symbol, not a macro.

Answer (score 0):

First a short background: before getting **compiled**, a `C` file is **pre-processed**. The **pre-processor** checks for `#include` and `#define` statements.

In your case, that `#define` statement tells the **pre-processor** to change every string `WIDTH` in your source code with the string `10`. When the file gets **compiled** in the next step, every occurance of `WIDTH` will be in fact `10`. Now, the difference between

```
#define WIDTH 10
```

and

```
int width = 10;
```

is that the first one can be seen as a `constant` value, whereas the second is a normal variable whose value can be changed.

Comment: `const` seems to have been there since C89.

Answer (score 0):

One `#define` is handled by the preprocessor, if finds `WIDTH` in the source code and it replaces it with `10`, all it does is basic substitution among other things, the other `int width = 10;` is handled by the compiler, this will create entries in the look up table, generate binaries to allocate enough memory on the stack, depending where its define, and copy the value 10 to that memory location.

So one is nothing more than a label for a constant, the other is a variable at run time.

You can use preprocessors for faster execution, since variables need to be allocated on the stack, at the cost of not being mutable at run time.

You usually use preprocessors for things that don't need to change at run time, though be careful preprocessors can be a bit tricky to debug, since they can actually manipulate the source code before its handed of to the compiler, leading to very subtle bugs, that may or may not be apparent examining the source code.

Answer (score 0):

Define is like a static global definition scope. It is not to be changed or over-written as a normal variable.

Comment: (This post does not seem to provide a [quality answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) to the question. Please either edit your answer, or just post it as a comment to the question).