# Error in switch & case?

Tags: c

I am confused with the following C code:

```
int main()
{
 const int i=2;

 switch(2)
 {
   case 1:
     printf("this is case 1");
     break;
   case i:
     printf("it should be case 2");
 }
```

I know after the keyword `case`, there should be a constant expression.

As have declared `i` as a constant, why is this code giving a compilation error?

Comment: you have a semi-colon after `case i` and it should be a colon

Comment: switch (2) seems kind of weird

Answer (score 9):

Because in C a `const` is not a true compile-time constant. It's just a read-only object. There's a [C FAQ](http://c-faq.com/ansi/constasconst.html) about this very subject.

Comment: If this was C++, then the code would be eccentric (`switch (2)` is not very sensible) but it would work.

Answer (score 2):

Constant variables are still not constant expressions. Constexprs (as referred to commonly) have to contain literals and compile-time constants only.

Answer (score 2):

Reasons:

1.`const` cannot be used in a switch statement. You could use a `#define/enum` though. Refer [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1674032/static-const-vs-define-in-c).

2.There is no `break` for the second case.

3.There is no `default` case.

4.There should be a colon after `case`.

Answer (score 0):

It is because you are using variable in you code.You can't use a variable in case statement.
Here  a is assumed as variable

> The compiler is explicitly allowed to use an efficient binary tree or
>   a jump table to evaluate case statements.
>
> For this reason, case statements are compile time constants.

The C99 standard says this (and the C89 standard was very similar):

> §6.8.4.2 The switch statement
>
> Constraints
>
> ¶1 The controlling expression of a switch statement shall have integer
>   type.
>
> [...]
>
> ¶3 The expression of each case label shall be an integer constant
>   expression and no two of the case constant expressions in the same
>   switch statement shall have the same value after conversion. There may
>   be at most one default label in a switch statement.