# Passing define int to function as an argument

Tags: c++, arguments, c-preprocessor

I don't understand why the following code won't compile:

```
#include <iostream>
#define SHORT_NAME 4;

int func(int arg)
{
    return arg;
}

int main()
{
    return func(SHORT_NAME); // Error: expected a ')'
}
```

Should I be using `const int SHORT_NAME = 4` on line 2 instead?

Comment: Yes.⁣⁣⁣⁣⁣⁣⁣⁣⁣⁣⁣⁣⁣⁣⁣⁣⁣⁣⁣⁣⁣⁣⁣⁣⁣⁣⁣⁣⁣

Comment: Some style guides would reserve SHOUTY_NAMES for macros, so you could even write `const int short_name = 4;` ;-)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Remove the semi-colon from the macro `SHORT_NAME` as after preprocessing it is expanded to:

```
 return func(4;);
```

Or use `const int` as you suggest in the question. See ["static const" vs "#define" vs "enum"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1674032/static-const-vs-define-in-c) for a discussion on macros vs `const`.

Answer (score 3):

The preprocessor expands the MACRO name. So this:

```
return func(SHORT_NAME);
```

becomes this:

```
return func(4;);
```

that is definitely a syntax error, isn't?

So if you define the MACRO without `;` then it will work:

```
#define SHORT_NAME 4  //without ;
```

---

> Should I be using const int SHORT_NAME = 4 on line 2 instead?

YES. Go for it. Macros are evil, anyway (in most cases).

Answer (score 2):

You don't need the semicolon in your define. Write this instead

```
#define SHORT_NAME 4
```

But using `const int` is definitely a better choice when using C++.