# C/C++ - Is it Recommended to use const static or #define

Tags: c++, c, global-variables

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [“static const” vs “#define” in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1674032/static-const-vs-define-in-c)

My first thought is that this is implied, but is there ever a reason why you would use `const` instead of `#define`?

If you set a global variable, why would you ever want to change it, and wouldn't you want to protect it globally as well?

Comment: Can you give an example of a definition you're asking about?

Comment: What does it mean to "use const with #define"?

Comment: "why you would use const instead of #define" is the wrong question. It should be "why would you use #define instead of const?"  and the answer is "for no reason at all".

Comment: is your question about static const or just const?

Comment: Also, for this question, you should differentiate between C or C++.  C++ would *always* prefer static const, or const to #define.  C++ will only use the preprocessor when it is absolutely necessary.  C on the other hand will use the preprocessor more, so an example is needed to give a "correct" answer.

Comment: @JoshPetitt, C _has_ to use the preprocessor more, because a `const int` is not a valid constant expression so can't be used in as many places as in C++.

Comment: @JonathanWakely, yes agreed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Const usually replaces `#define`

`#define` is a pre-processor macro that can do **textual** replacement.  You can use it to define a constant or a macro or do all sorts of other things.

const is a type-safe way to define a compile-time constant

These two mechanisms occur at different times in the compilation process, but in general, const was created to rectify the problems of `#define`.

I've rarely seen people do something like

```
#define CONSTINT  const int
```

but it is legal.

Answer (score 4):

`const` is only relevant for variables that are passed around at runtime that ensures that subroutines cannot change them. `#define` is a preprocessor compiletime directive that replaces whatever you define with what you have defined it as. Therefore, they are for different purposes.

Answer (score 2):

**Edit** this is an answer to your original question, of whether you'd use `const` with a `define` ... it doesn't really make sense now you've edited the question to ask something different.

A `#define` does not define a variable, so you can't change it anyway, so the question doesn't  make sense.

This isn't even possible:

```
#define FOO 99

int main()
{
    FOO = 98;
}
```

Because the preprocessor substitutes the macro `FOO` for the replacement `99`, so the compiler sees this code:

```
int main()
{
    99 = 98;
}
```

And obviously that's nonsense. You can't assign to a literal, it's not a variable (const or not) it's just a value.