# variable length array folded to constant array

Tags: c, constantfolding

```
const int buf_length = 255;
char buf[ buf_length + 1 ];

snprintf(buf, buf_length, "%d Next on [%s] %s:", channel, station_channel(channel), station_name(channel));

strncat(buf, "(", buf_length - strlen (buf));
strncat(buf, station_country( xmltv ), buf_length - strlen(buf));
strncat(buf, ")", buf_length - strlen (buf));

country_list_set_text( buf );
```

This get warning:

> variable length array folded to constant array as an extension.

Can you help to solve this?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

In C, a `const int` variable is a variable (that happens to be `const`-qualified), rather than an integer constant that is required when used in the bounds of global and static arrays, or in the `case` labels of a `switch` statement.  See [`static const` vs `#define` in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1674032/static-const-vs-define-in-c/1674459#1674459) for an extensive discussion.  I'm assuming that you are aware of what a VLA (variable length array) is — if not, comment and I'll add clarification.

There are a couple of ways around it.  The one I normally use is an `enum`:

```
enum { buf_length = 255 };
char buf[buf_length + 1];

snprintf(buf, sizeof(buf), "%d Next on [%s] %s:",
         channel, station_channel(channel), station_name(channel));
```

Note that I changed the use of `buf_length` in the `snprintf()` call to `sizeof(buf)`; that is the canonical way to do it when the array declaration is in scope — and avoids wasting the extra byte you added to the buffer.

You could use `#define buf_length 255`; that is the classic way to do it.

I would often use an upper-case constant (`BUF_LENGTH`) rather than lower-case to designate a constant.  It isn't actually critical, but it is more or less conventional in C (witness the majority of the constants in the C standard, with oddball exceptions such as `L_tmpnam`).

In C++, the story is different.  The `const int buf_length = 255;` can be used in `switch` statements and array bounds.

Answer (score 9):

The `buf_length + 1` is not treated as a compile-time constant expression.

Replacing the second declaration with

```
char buf[256];
```

should fix the problem.

You may want to replace `buf_length` with a `#define`:

```
#define BUF_LENGTH 255
char buf[BUF_LENGTH + 1];
```