# Where should constant data be stored for an app?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm making a simple memory game to learn more about iPhone programming and I am wondering how I should be storing constant information.

For example:

- The probability of a certain color being more prominent.
- The threshold that decides what constitutes a double touch event.
- ...

Data like this is internal game data that is unlikely to change.

Should I be putting these as constants in the `ViewController` where they are used?
Should I `#define` them?

Comment: \If you save values dynamically and retrieving then you can user core data or Plist or sqlite or NSUserDefualt... its all depends on your requirement and size of data.

Comment: @iAmbitious No it's not.

Comment: @GabrielePetronella i edited my comment read it.

Comment: @iAmbitious Still no. `#define` is a terrible way. Use a `const` variable instead.

Comment: There is no good answer for the general question.  One can use `#defines`, enums, consts, values loaded from a plist, etc.  Each has advantages and disadvantages.  One favorite of mine is to define a global dictionary with named tuning/customization values in it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a difference.

If you want to **store** constants, then use `NSUserDefaults`.

If you just want them to be there, in your code, just lying there then, `#define` should be fine.

Comment: `#define` can be dangerous, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1674032/static-const-vs-define-in-c