# How do I define a value that is the sum of other predefined values in C?

Tags: c, c-preprocessor

How can I use `#define` to say that one value consists of the sum of two other values. Would it be allowed and good practice in **C** to do something like this?

```
#define VALUE_A 2
#define VALUE_B 2
#define SUM_A_B (VALUE_A + VALUE_B)
```

If not, what should I do to achieve this functionality?

Comment: It works and I do it all the time.

Comment: It would be interesting to write a small program with this in it (it is valid and looks reasonable - just as long as you remember the parentheses) then look at the compiled code. I am 99% sure the compiler will evaluate the sum into a simple constant so there is no performance penalty at runtime. Anyone care to check?

Comment: [BOOST_PP_ADD](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_41_0/boost/preprocessor/arithmetic/add.hpp)

Comment: @Floris: The compiler is required to *be aware* that it's a constant expression, because there are different rules about where you can and cannot use non-constant expressions (or where semantics are different based on whether you have a constant expression). There's nothing that requires it to actually evaluate the value at compile-time, but it would be gratuitously stupid not to do so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just need that for integer constants (type `int`) you may use enumerations for this type of constants

```
enum { SUM_A_B = (VALUE_A + VALUE_B), };
```

possible advantages:

- the sum is only evaluated once by the compiler. This is not a big
  deal for modern compilers if this is only such a simple sum, but
  could make a small difference when you are using more complicated
  expressions
- even nowadays compiler errors and debugging information isn't that
  good for values coming from the preprocessor. Enumeration constants usually can be traced well.

A disadvantage is that the value itself is not accessible in the preprocessor itself. So you can't do `#if/#else` constructs with it. But you could at least still define it as

```
#define SUM_A_B SUM_A_B
```

So `#ifdef/#else` constructs would still work.

Comment: That's a slightly modified form of the discussion in [`static const` vs `#define` in C](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1674032).

Answer (score 2):

The Linux and GCC header files do it routinely, if that's a vote of confidence.  e.g.:

```
$ grep -r 'define.*+' /usr/include/
...
/usr/include/linux/fdreg.h:#define FD_STATUS    (4 + FD_IOPORT )
...
/usr/include/linux/elf.h:#define PT_GNU_STACK   (PT_LOOS + 0x474e551)
...
/usr/include/i386-linux-gnu/asm/unistd_32.h:#define __NR_timer_settime  (__NR_timer_create+1)
```

etc.