# Definition of constant variable vs. #define

Tags: c, parameters, c-preprocessor

I would like to understand the difference between defining a constant variable as follows:

```
const int ONE = 1;
```

and using a preprocessor directive:

```
#define ONE (1)
```

I know that in the second case "1" gets in some sense hardcoded and the compiler does not even see the variable ONE, but I am not sure about the first case. The fact of declaring the variable as constant just prevents from accidentally change its value, or does the compiler catch the opportunity to do some optimization? Is there any significant benefit of one approach over the other?

Comment: @AlokSave: That question is about C++

Comment: This http://stackoverflow.com/a/1674118/1809377 and this http://stackoverflow.com/a/1674459/1809377 answer your question definitively.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In C, `const int c;` means that `c` can't be modified during the run of program. However, `c` is not a constant during compile time and can not be used in constant expressions. So for example the program:

```
const int MAX = 10;
int a[MAX];
```

does not compile, while:

```
#define MAX 10
int a[MAX];
```

does.

In C++, `const` variables are true compile-time constants, so there may be less reasons to use `#define` for it. An example where `#define` is necessary is when you need to use the constant in an `#if` directive.

Comment: what about variable-length arrays? `int a[MAX];` would compile just fine.

Comment: Of course, variable length arrays are called variable length because they do not require constant expression as dimension. They can be used for local variables only.