# What's the correct way to fix stack protector: variable length buffer warning?

Tags: c

I have a series of about 30 functions which use local arrays as such:

```
void foo() {
  const int array_size = 32;
  char my_array[array_size];

  // .. do stuff
  // (array_size is used multiple times)
}
```

The code (when compiling with `-Wstack-protector`) will produce the following warning message:

`warning: stack protector not protecting local variables: variable length buffer`

So I have two questions:

First, why is `my_array` considered variable length?  Yea, I know why technically, but shouldn't the compiler be smart enough to realize that it isn't *really* variable length?

Second, what is the most appropriate way to fix this warning?  I know I can fix it by doing something like:

```
void foo() {
  char my_array[32];
  const int array_size = sizeof(my_array) / sizeof(my_array[0]);

  // .. do stuff
  // (array_size is used multiple times)
}
```

but is there a better, more "correct" way?

Comment: Is this C or C++? In C89, I get the variable length buffer warning, but not in C99/11 or C++03/11/14 (with clang).

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1674032/static-const-vs-define-in-c

Comment: Yes, for this current build I'm trying it's C89 (Explains why I'm only seeing them now)

Comment: @amurka: then tag it as c, not c++.

Comment: Yes, apologies for that.

Comment: Must be missing something. I tried clang and gcc -c89 -Wall -Wstack-protector and the above had no warnings. I'm on gcc 4.2.1. Maybe this was fixed. Anyway, you tried static const size_t for the array size? size_t is better than int too.

Comment: Can't reproduce in clang-503.0.40, with either `--std=c89`, `--std=c99`, or no standard specified.

Comment: `char my_array[array_size];` is illegal in C89. (gcc implements it as an extension)

Comment: So maybe I'm not using C89 then??? Or is that why I'm getting the warning?

Answer (score 3):

```
const int array_size = 32;
```

Does **NOT** make `array_size` a constant. It merely means that it cannot be used for assignment as an lvalue. (it's value can be changed otherwise). Therefore it is not allowed as a `constant literal` in:

```
char my_array[array_size];
```

You can either:

```
#DEFINE array_size  32
```

or

```
enum { array_size = 32 };
```

Comment: No, its value cannot be changed otherwise.   Whether it is "a constant" depends on your definition of that term. It is `const`, it is not writable, it is not an *integer constant expression*.

Answer (score -1):

You probably should allocate dynamically your array as:

```
void foo() {
  const int array_size = 32;
  char *my_array;
  my_array = malloc((array_size)*sizeof(char));
  // .. do stuff
  // (array_size is used multiple times)

  free(my_array);
}
```

Comment: The question is C, not C++.

Comment: sorry, thought was c++