# Linux Kernel: Static Const vs #Define

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel

Which is more "appropriate" when writing  a linux kernel module:  Using `static const` to define a constant, or `#define` ?

I have a kernel module related to a piece of hardware, and I have a typical constant that's the number of buffers.  Rather than hard-code "3" everywhere, I want to use a constant.  C style usually recommends taking `static const`, but I notice the Kernel is chock full of `#define`'s all over the place.  Is there a reason?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1674032/static-const-vs-define-in-c

Comment: Yeah, I've read that.. I'm just wondering if there are other implications when working in the Kernel space that change the answers slightly.

Comment: Follow the convention of the project you're working on. As linux is already using #define for hardware masks/registers/values, use the same convention.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It used to be that you couldn't do:

```
const size_t buffer_size = 1024;
unsigned char buffer[buffer_size];
```

in C, since `buffer_size` is not a "real" constant. Therefore you often see

```
#define BUFFER_SIZE 1024
unsigned char buffer[BUFFER_SIZE];
```

instead.

As of C99, you *can* do the former, but *not* in global scope. It won't work outside of a function (not even if made `static`). Since much code in the kernel deals with similiar constructs, that might be one reason for using the preprocessor instead.

Note: don't forget about `sizeof`, it's a very good tool when it comes to not repeating the size constant all over the place, regardless of how the constant was implemented.

Comment: Yeah, I know sizeof.. Unfortunately, this constant is defined by external hardware requirements, and must be known a-priori (I can't query for this number, it just must be known to be 3).