# is #define PFUser good practice

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, parse-platform

I'm working with Parse.com and in a lot of VC's I'm calling `PFUser *currentUser = [PFUser currentUser];`

I figured it might be good practice to `#define` `currentUser` in the prefix file. Is that good practice?

Also, how do I define an object like this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically #define is almost never a good practice. We have been trying to get away from them for a couple of decades.

When a developer reads `currentUser` he will not know what is happening, it will be a WTF moment. WTF moments are to be avoided, according to Uncle Bob the quality of code can be measured in the units: "WTFs/min". If you really want to do something like this make a one-line method or property.

Go for the most understandable code to the next developer in the future--it may even be you!

Comment: I don't think currentUser will cause a WTF moment. currentUser.name is pretty good readable.

Comment: @bdv only until after few years someone else is trying declare `MyUser *currentUser` which translate to `MyUser *[PFUser currentUser]`

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using a `#define`, you should use a `static const`.

```
static const PFUser *kCurrentUser = [PFUser currentUser];
```

By convention the lowercase k is added in front of the constant name to indicate that it is a constant. If you want to read more on why `static const` is preferred over `#define`, look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1674032/static-const-vs-define-in-c).

Comment: thanks, that's a good one i guess. However it's not quite static. Values of the user can change. Should I still call it a const then?

Comment: No, because static variables can only be assigned once. If `[PFUser currentUser]` ever changes, then unfortunately your best bet is to just stick with that particular method call or store a reference to `currentUser` every time it is defined or changes.