# How to reuse a literal in a char and a one-character string constant?

Tags: c, string

I need to specify an argument short option (e.g. `-F`) both as `char` and `char[]` constant in c code. In order to maximize code reusage I want to declare a variable which allows me to change the value in one place (a "literal" - not stringly speaking a string or `char` literal, but in the sense of the abstract concept). I would prefer a solution which solves this exclusively in preprocessor constants and functions/macros or exclusively in c code to a good explanation why this has to be solved in a mixture of both.

I tried/checked out

- to `#define FOREGROUND_OPTION_VALUE 'F'` which causes me trouble to transform it to a `char[]` (as preprocessor constant) (writing a macro which stringifies with `#` causes the `'` quotes to be stringified as well
- to omit the `'` quotes which leaves me with the problem of creating the `'` quotes or create a `char` another way.
- @PedroWitzel's answer to declare a `char[]` and use the 0th `char` for another constant. That's fine, but I'd prefer a way to create the `char[]` from the `char` because that enforces both to be equal (otherwise I'd have to add a compile time assertion that `char[]` isn't longer than `1`).

The only thing that matters for me is code maintenance, nothing else (like cost in processing the code (during compilation or runtime - have not reflected intensively if there could be any and don't care)).

Comment: Saving one character of data is only worthwhile if there is (literally) no cost in the code processing it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Over and above the discussion in [comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29868286/how-to-reuse-a-literal-in-a-char-and-a-one-character-string-variable?noredirect=1#comment47862113_29868508) to [Pedro Witzel](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1449839/pedro-witzel)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29868508/15168), there's another option:

```
#define FOREGROUND_OPTION_VALUE 'F'

static const char fg_opt_str[] = { FOREGROUND_OPTION_VALUE, '\0' };
```

It's not a commonly used way of initializing a string, but it is a valid one and seems appropriate for your scenario.  Now you can use FOREGROUND_OPTION_VALUE where you need a constant `char` (or `int`) value, and `fg_opt_str` where you need a one-character string.  If you change the value defined (to `f`, say), then you only have to change one place for the code to continue to work, assuming you weren't using `f` before, which meets your maintainability requirement.

Comment: Thanks. As mentioned in my question a statement on whether this mixture of preprocessor definition and c source code is _necessary_ (besides the fact it's absolutely valid) would be appreciated.

Comment: It depends on what you want to do.  It might not be necessary if your code deals only with strings, or only with character constants.  But if you need both and they need to be kept in sync automatically, then you'll need some technique along the lines outline here and by Pedro Witzel to do the job.  Which works best for you depends on your requirements.  We can't see enough of your code to be able to advise on that.

Comment: I need a constant and didn't point that out in the initial question which was not very smart. It's clear if I need a constant, only, though?!

Comment: If you need something that's a string literal — for string concatenation, etc. — as well as a character constant, then I don't know that there's a way to get that; we're back to where we started.  Some things aren't worth fighting over.  You could arrange to generate the code that has to be kept in sync: for example, given a specification `FOREGROUND_OPTION F`, your code generator might generate `#define FOREGROUND_OPTION_VALUE 'F'` and `#define FOREGROUND_OPTION_STRING "F"` — the code generator could be as simple a `sed` script.

Answer (score 2):

A [static constant](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1674032/static-const-vs-define-in-c) variable would work for you?

```
static const char FOREGROUND_OPTION_VALUE[] = "F";
```

Comment: How does that reuse the specification of `F` for a `char` and  a `char[]` at one place?

Comment: @KarlRichter: when you need the string you use `FOREGROUND_OPTION_VALUE`, when you need the `char` you use `*FOREGROUND_OPTION_VALUE`.

Comment: @KarlRichter: You use `FOREGROUND_OPTION_VALUE` when you want a string and `FOREGROUND_OPTION_VALUE[0]` or  `*FOREGROUND_OPTION_VALUE`when you want a single character.  This is as good as it gets.  You won't be able to use this as a `case` label in a `switch` statement, but other than that, it should be workable.  You can also use `#define FOREGROUND_OPTION_VALUE "F"` as in the question, and either of the expressions I suggested to access the character.

Comment: I don't think you'll be able to use the same variable for two different types, witch are essentially char and char*. I'd say the best way to go is to cast properly, as suggested by @JonathanLeffler. It would improve readability and code maintenance as you'd be certain that you use the right type.