# Understanding to declare array length

Tags: c, coding-style

So, with this I make a VLA:

```
int main()
{
    const size_t LEN = 200; // as I know it's read-onlyy
    int array[LEN];
}
```

So I enstablished that VLAs are not more requested in C1.. In the C99 today they are optional... For this motivaiton, to use that code is not advised.

But if I do this:

```
#define MYLEN 100
int main()
{
    int xar[MYLEN];
}
```

or

```
int main()
{
    int xar[100];
    const size_t MYLEN = sizeof(xar) / sizeof(int);
}
```

I think I have:

- In the first case I have a constant variable in the compile time, but it's more logic and not typed.
- In the second case, a typed variable, (read-only)

But with it's more valid with the define directive as it's typical to C language.What do you suggest to use?

Anyway, the VLA can be used inside the main but it has not so sense.

Comment: This is somehow opinion based.

Comment: It's difficult to understand everything in your question.

Comment: @PCLuddite what don't you understand?

Comment: Consider [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1674032/static-const-vs-define-in-c) dealing with the differences between both approaches.

Answer (score 0):

the posted code has no VLAs defined as the sizing is always known at compile time.

This would be an example of a VLA:

```
int myFunction( int size )
{
    int myArray[size];
}
```

Comment: Why are not them a VLA?

Comment: This answer is wrong. The first version in the question is well a VLA. As soon as the expression in the `[]` depends on an object, this is a VLA. This is how the C standard defines it.

Comment: Just to clear up what @JensGustedt sir said, a `const` variable is not a compile time constant in `C`, it it called `const`-qualified.