# Access violation reading location 0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF

Tags: c++, access-violation

I'm attempting to use OpenGL to demonstrate hierarchical animation. In the early stage I'm trying to give my "bone" object a reference to its parent.

In my bone class, I can add a parent successfully however the issue is when I call `hasParent()`. It can't read this->parent and crashes with the following exception:

> Unhandled exception at 0x00007FF6CB723D43 in myprogram.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF.**

Snippets from my bone class:

```
void Bone::addParent(Bone *bone)
{
    this->parent = bone;
    assert(this->parent);
}

bool Bone::hasParent()
{
    assert(this->parent); //this line causes the error
    if (this->parent)
        return true;
    else return false;
}

glm::mat4 Bone::getBoneModel()
{
    glm::mat4 parentModel = glm::mat4(1.0);
    if (hasParent())
        parentModel = parent->getBoneModel();
    //boneModel = parentModel * boneModel;
    return boneModel;
}
```

Stripped down content of my main:

```
#define NUMBONES 3
Bone bone[NUMBONES];

int main( void )
{
    //------------------ Create Bones --------------------------
    float y = 0.0f;
    for (int i = 0; i < NUMBONES; i++)
    {
        bone[i] = Bone(i, vec3(0, y, -30), vec3(0, 0, 0), vec3(0, 0, 0));
        y += 5.0f;
    }

    //----------------- Make relationships ----------------
    bone[0].isRoot = true;
    bone[0].addChild(&bone[1]);
    bone[0].addChild(&bone[2]);
    bone[1].addParent(&bone[0]);
    bone[1].addChild(&bone[2]);
    bone[2].addParent(&bone[1]);

    do{
        ModelMatrix = bone[1].getBoneModel();
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I find references and pointers difficult to get my head around so I'm hoping this is obvious to someone else!

EDIT:

My constructors:

```
Bone::Bone() {
    parent = NULL;
    child = NULL;
    boneID = 0;
    boneModel = glm::mat4(1.0);
}

Bone::Bone(int ID, glm::vec3 T, glm::vec3 R, glm::vec3 S)
{
    boneID = ID;
    isRoot = false;
    pos = T;

    //---------- set boneModel ------------------
    glm::mat4 RotationMatrix = glm::mat4(1.0);
    glm::mat4 TranslationMatrix = translate(glm::mat4(), pos);
    glm::mat4 ScalingMatrix = scale(glm::mat4(), glm::vec3(1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f));
    boneModel = TranslationMatrix * RotationMatrix * ScalingMatrix;

    std::cout << "bone[" << boneID << "] created.\n";

}
```

Comment: You may find this a lot easier if you run this in the debugger, and get a stack trace from where the error occurred.

Comment: Please show the constructor of `Bone` class. Does it initialize `parent`?

Comment: Which line of code is causing the fault?

Comment: I'm not initializing parent in the constructor. The error is the first line of hasParent(), assert(this->parent).

Comment: You should initialize parent and child in  `Bone::Bone(int ID, glm::vec3 T, glm::vec3 R, glm::vec3 S)` otherwise it will have a random garbage value.

Comment: @drescherjm Thank you! This solved it!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add

```
parent = NULL;
child = NULL;
```

to second constructor `Bone(int ID, glm::vec3 T, glm::vec3 R, glm::vec3 S)`

Comment: Optimally, this should be done in the initializer list. Not that important for primitive types, but e.g., for `boneModel` setting it in the constructor will cause the default mat4 constructor to run unnecessarily.

Answer (score 4):

You do not need

```
assert(this->parent)
```

in the first line of Bone::hasParent(). Asserting something means you expect it always to be true. But then why do you have the function hasParent() in the first place? When this line is executed and there parent is not initialized, your program crashes. It should work if you remove the assert.

Then you should initialize parent & child in the second constructor as well (presumably with nullptr).

Not related to your problem, but to improve your C++ style, you should not use #define's to define constants. Use const instead, e.g.

```
const unsigned int NUM_BONES
```

See, e.g., ["static const" vs "#define" vs "enum"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1674032/static-const-vs-define-vs-enum)

Comment: Still get the same error with the line after if(this->parent) if the assert is taken out

Comment: That can't be reason of this error... Problem is that parent is not initialized in all constructors

Comment: @Claire Even though that assert was not your current problem, it will become one as soon as you call hasParent() on a Bone which does not have one.

Answer (score 1):

Solved by @drescherjm:

I needed to initialize 'parent = NULL' in Bone::Bone(int ID, glm::vec3 T, glm::vec3 R, glm::vec3 S)

```
Bone::Bone(int ID, glm::vec3 T, glm::vec3 R, glm::vec3 S)
{
    parent = NULL;
    boneID = ID;
    isRoot = false;
    pos = T;

    //---------- set boneModel ------------------
    glm::mat4 RotationMatrix = glm::mat4(1.0);
    glm::mat4 TranslationMatrix = translate(glm::mat4(), pos);
    glm::mat4 ScalingMatrix = scale(glm::mat4(), glm::vec3(1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f));
    boneModel = TranslationMatrix * RotationMatrix * ScalingMatrix;

    std::cout << "bone[" << boneID << "] created.\n";

}
```

Comment: Initialize child also.