# Distinguish and expand text macro nested in define macro

Tags: verilog, cadence

I would like to define a parameter `MYTYPE` using text macro, whose value is passed over by text macro, eg

```
`define MY_FEATURE(nam,def) parameter nam=def;
```

and then

```
`MY_FEATURE(MYTYPE, 1)
```

But the value is mixed by those who are defined by other text macros, eg

```
`MY_FEATURE(NEWTYPE, 2)
`MY_FEATURE(MYTYPE, NEWTYPE)
```

The latter case will not work unless the `def` in `define MY_FEATURE` is added with the directive dot.

I need to distinguish this two different cases and automatically expand the macro - only if it is defined, so I came up with this code but I got error.

```
`define yea 1
`define nop 0
`define MY_FEATURE(nam,def) `ifdef def parameter nam=`def; `else parameter nam=2; `endif

module test;

  `MY_FEATURE(MYTYPE,yea)
  initial begin
    $display("%d",MYTYPE);
  end
endmodule
```

The above code works and gives a `1` as output. However if I write

```
`MY_FEATURE(MYTYPE,10)
```

since for other cases I need to assign an actual number to the parameter, then I will get

```
 `ifdef without a macro name - ignored.
```

My desired result is `MYTYPE` is assigned as 10. 
Is there any way to achieve this? Thanks.

Code can be found here
http://www.edaplayground.com/x/6Jha

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are overthinking it. `` `define `` creates an directive expression. When when you pass a directive as parameter to another directive you can pass it as `` `yea ``.

Here is an example:

```
`define yea 1
`define nop 0
`define MY_FEATURE(nam,def) parameter nam=def;

module test;
  `MY_FEATURE(MYTYPE,`yea)
  `MY_FEATURE(MYTYPE2,10)
  `MY_FEATURE(MYTYPE3,MYTYPE+MYTYPE2)
  initial begin
    $display("%d %d %d",MYTYPE, MYTYPE2, MYTYPE3); // displays: 1 10 11
  end
endmodule
```

http://www.edaplayground.com/x/5Pgf

---

Verilog-AMS (superset of Verilog-A) is a language of its own, derived from Verilog (IEEE Std 1364); according the [manual](http://accellera.org/downloads/standards/v-ams). This means your `MY_FEATURE` never creates new directives; it creates parameters. Directives and parameters are both treated as constants in simulation but act differently in compile. The `` `define ``/`parameters` relation in Verilog (and Verilog derived languages) is equivalent to [C's `#define`/`const`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1674032/1959732) relation. Unlike C, to access the value of a `` `define `` requires a `` ` `` prefix.

Neither directives or parameters cannot start with a numeric value. The first character must be an alpha or underscore (aka `[a-zA-Z_]`). There for `10` can never be a directives and even trying to use it is illegal syntax. There is noway for the compile to recover from an illegal syntax directive name. This is way I suggested passing `` `yea `` instead of `yea`.

If someone build you a *nice* model, then it should come with equally *nice* documentation or some way of getting support.

Comment: Thank you. It works in system verilog but i'm actually using verilog a. they build a pretty large (and nice) model of a real device and use lots of directive statements to define constants. i believe they have used hspice but i can only use virtuoso / spectre and they don't seem to like this setting.

Comment: I'll append my comment to my answer as it is a bit long and code formatted \` in comments do not format well

Comment: Thank you, Greg. Now i understand there is little way i could get around this. i believe they are nice people making things accepted by the industry, but i don't see any documentation on the code itself besides the one on the physical model they create. i as a beginner am using my common sense in verilog/vhdl coding. Just replaced a few hundreds of statements that refer to other parameters - at least it works!