# Assigning members of a const variable to another const

Tags: c, struct, constants

I'm trying to define two `const` variables with the same data structure. I want to ensure that all of the members of each variable are exactly the same except for the one that I am changing. Since I do not want to maintain two exact copies of the same code, I thought "why not use the existing members in one to initialize the other?"

Here is an example in code:

```
typedef struct {
    int a;
    int b;
} aStruct;

const aStruct foo = {
    .a = 10,
    .b = 20
};

const aStruct bar = {
    .a = 15,
    .b = foo.b
};
```

When I try to compile this code, I get an error:

```
foo.c:13:14: error: initializer element is not constant
         .b = foo.b
              ^~~
foo.c:13:14: note: (near initialization for ‘bar.b’)
```

I'm fairly new to C, so I don't fully understand how constants and data structures work, especially when they are put together. Can someone help me figure out what is going on here?

Comment: Use a#define to share a value.

Comment: This is tricky territory, but I think the problem is that `const` isn't as constant as you'd like.  At file scope (as opposed to function scope), you can't write: `static const int N = 100;` and `static aStruct as_array[N];` either; the value of N is not considered to be a compile-time constant and the array size must be a compile-time constant.  You can often use addresses as initializers in similar circumstances because the address is fixed (by the linker — the last phase of 'compile-time' processing).  But I think you're running into this "`const` isn't really constant" problem.

Comment: A corollary to what I was saying: you'd not be able to use `static aStruct as_data[foo.a];` either — in this case, neither at file scope nor function scope (but drop the `static` and it would be fine at function scope).  See also [`static const` vs `#define` vs `enum` in C](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1674032/).  This is not a duplicate of that, but it may shed some light on the issue you're facing.

Comment: Your title already said it: "Assigning members of a const **variable** ...". C does not have symbolic constants (except enum-constants).

Comment: You intention is perfectly clear: `foo.b` has already been initialized so why doesn't the compiler use that value? But note that `.b = foo.b` requires _instructions_ (get address of `foo`, add offset to `b`, get value of `b`) and instructions can only be executed in functions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because you are trying to initialize global variables at file scope, and at that scope only constants (`foo.b` is not) can be used to initialize values. My compiler gives a better message:

> ```
> error: initializer element is not a compile-time constant
>     .b = foo.b
>          ~~~~^ 1 error generated.
> ```

If you had tried to do the same at block scope, that would have been correct:

```
typedef struct {
    int a;
    int b;
} aStruct;

int main() {
  const aStruct foo = {
    .a = 10,
    .b = 20
  };

  const aStruct bar = {
    .a = 15,
    .b = foo.b
  };
}
```

So, you'd better use some defines to initialize your global variables to the same value.

Comment: I have a problem with that solution. Members of the struct in the actual application are structs themselves, so using #defines is pretty hard. However, it does answer the example I've given, so thanks!

Comment: @AdamGausmann: there are compound literals and designated initializers that can be used `(struct WhatEver){ .we_member1 = VALUE1, .we_member3 = VALUE3 }` etc.  That can be wrapped in `#define`.  Or maybe you should use (constant) pointers to other (constant) structures? Or some combination.  I'm not keen on `#define`, but if this is going to be repeated multiple times, using a macro to avoid repetition is a good idea.