# strange behavior of #define command

Tags: c

I've tried to figure out this behavior of the define command in C (I'm new with that). I've got this code and I don't know why I see in the output that myAge=15 and not 16 (I know it's 15, but I don't know why). Anybody can help me to find out why does it happen?

this is the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h> 
#define AGE 15; 

int main(void)
{
    float myAge = AGE + 1;
    printf("Hello!\n");  
    printf("My name is Raz and I am %d years old!\n", myAge);

    system("PAUSE");

    return 0;
}
```

Thanks for helping :)

Comment: See [`static const` vs `#define` vs `enum`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1674032/static-const-vs-define-vs-enum/) for a run-down of the relative merits of different ways of defining constant values.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`#define` is a textual replacement performed by the preprocessor prior to the compilation step. In this case, you're asking the preprocessor to expand the token `AGE` to `15;`. The semicolon is part of the expansion, so this is the code you would get after the preprocessing step:

```
float myAge = 15; + 1;
```

As you can see, it does not expand to what you expect.

You can fix this issue by removing the semicolon from the `#define`:

```
#define AGE 15
```

Better yet, avoid using the preprocessor for simple numerical constants - consider using a `const int` instead:

```
const int age = 15;
```

Comment: Is there a benefit in avoiding using the preprocessor? I thought that `#define`ing an integer caused it to be calculated at compile time (thus faster at runtime), whereas a `const` wouldn't be.

Comment: thank you about that. that is very useful for me! :)

Comment: *"As you can see, it is invalid C code."* – Actually it is *valid* C code (otherwise it would not compile and produce the unexpected output).

Comment: @Addison - you are incorrect, In this case and many others using `const int...` is a lot better. You have the power of type safety as well

Comment: @EdHeal - I'm willing to accept that I'm wrong, and you raise a good point about type safety, but I will not accept "using `const int...` is a lot better" as a reason. Just why is it a lot better?

Comment: @EdHeal - A quick search showed up some reasons as to why `consts` are preferred: you can use pointers to consts, unlike with defined values, and you can give them the appropriate scope to improve code readability and minimise abuse of the variable. Additionally, const values are visible to debugging tools.

Comment: @addison - I think you have just answered your own question.

Comment: Yep. I suppose they are "a lot better", but it's good that I know why

Comment: @addison - At least you know and by doing a little research you understand why

Comment: @MartinR: fixed, thanks.