# Using define macro and its value in quotes

Tags: c, macros, preprocessor-directive

Writing some C code just out of curiosity and I'd like to move some values for a MySQL connection to a kind of `const`.

**Question 1**
Is it a good idea to store host, user etc in preprocessor macros? I.e.:

```
#include <my_global.h>
#include <mysql.h>

#define DB_HOST "mysqlhost.com"
#define DB_USER "mysqlusername"
#define DB_TABLE "tablename"
...
```

To use them later like `mysql_real_connect(con, DB_HOST, DB_USER, DP_PASS, DB_NAME, 0, NULL, 0) == NULL)`
?

**Question 2**

Can I use `DB_TABLE`'s value inside a quoted string? I.e. `mysql_query(con, "SELECT * FROM DB_TABLE")`

If so - what is corrcect way to use it here?

Comment: Regarding the first question, check this answer about the advantages of const vs define (vs enum): https://stackoverflow.com/a/1674459/7520531

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Answer 1:** Technically, you can define it the way you have shown, but at times, it makes sense to make the parameters which are likely to change (like hostname, username) as environment variables, and [read them during the program execution](https://linux.die.net/man/3/getenv). This makes your program more robust against frequent changes. The parameters which are to remain same, can surely be used as a `#define` preprocessor (like tablename).

A sample can be found [here](http://www0.cs.ucl.ac.uk/staff/ucacbbl/getenv/).

**Answer 2:** No, you cannot use it like that. However, since pre-processor MACROS are compile time substitution, you can take advantage of string concatenation, like

```
mysql_query(con, "SELECT * FROM " DB_TABLE);
```

where `DB_TABLE` is defined as a MACRO.

Answer (score 4):

> Is it a good idea to store host, user etc in preprocessor macros?

It is common practise, at least if the values can be considered constant in the context of the program.

Alternatively you can define constants by doing:

```
const char * db_host = "localhost";
```

The drawback here is that the simple concatenation as shown below won't work.

> Can I use `DB_TABLE`'s value inside a quoted string?

No, but you can just do:

```
mysql_query(con, "SELECT * FROM " DB_TABLE);
```

Comment: @SouravGhosh: Absolutely!

Comment: I don't think that is common practice to store values such as hostname and username in MACROS! ... It's common for very small applications ... ;)

Comment: @SirJoBlack: Well I, generalised the question to whether it were common to #define strings. If to do so for host or user names made sense at least depends .... Reworded my answer.