# Defining constant in c with const keyword

Tags: c, constants

Can you define a constant using the `const` keyword in C.

I am finding conflicting information.

Used the #define macro and hard code the value to test. The code will compile in those cases but is throwing an error when I use the const keyword.

```c
int main(void){

  const int  TESTARRAYSIZE = 7;
  float user_array[TESTARRAYSIZE] = {5.1, 7.2, 5.1, 8.45, 23.0,
                                       67.123, 5.1};
  float number_in_question = 5.1;

  float frequency;

  frequency = user_array[1];

  printf("%.2f", frequency);

  return(0);
}
```

compile error:
`<filename>:22:3: error: variable-sized object may not be initialized`

but this error largely seems to be coming because the constant isn't setting the value.

Comment: `const`-qualified variables are not constant expressions

Comment: I'm seeing this being explained otherwise in a few different places:

https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cprogramming/c_constants.htm

https://www.w3schools.in/c-tutorial/constants/

Comment: Those sites are wrong

Comment: This is one of the key differences between C and C++.  `const`-qualified variables in C++ are true compile-time constants and can be used for things like array sizes, but this is *not* true in C.  I suspect the misinformation you've seen stems from authors who assume that what they know about C++ is true for C (perhaps because they don't understand that the two languages are different).

Comment: See also ["static const" vs "#define" vs "enum"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1674032/static-const-vs-define-vs-enum/).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using the `const` type qualifier doesn't make something a constant.  A constant in C has its own definition.

See § 6.7.3 ¶ 6 of the C11 standard for a description of the `const` keyword:

> If an attempt is made to modify an object defined with a const-qualified type through use of an lvalue with non-const-qualified type, the behavior is undefined. If an attempt is made to refer to an object defined with a volatile-qualified type through use of an lvalue with non-volatile-qualified type, the behavior is undefined.

What you need there is a constant expression; see § 6.6 of C11 for details.

If what you're really wondering isn't "WTF is up with the `const` qualifier?" but rather what the right solution for your code is, the answer is likely to simply not specify the size of the array:

```
float user_array[] = {5.1, 7.2, 5.1, 8.45, 23.0, 67.123, 5.1};
```

This is generally considered good practice as it actually makes your code a bit more robust.

Comment: No, the code doesn't matter. Just a little confused because I've seeing bad information on the use of contestants using keyword. 
This gives me a better place to start thank you.

Comment: This is the best option, and conforms to every version of ISO C. Further, if you want to access the size, `const size_t user_array_size = sizeof user_array / sizeof *user_array;` and it will be updated automatically.

Answer (score 1):

The compiler throws an error because when using stack memory the variables are allocated by the compiler in the pre-compilation stage, The size of the array must be a known value to the compiler in this stage

As you said if you `#define` the value there would be no error due to the fact it's a known hardcoded value.

Comment: In `C99`, one can have variable-length arrays, but `C11` made it a conditional feature. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable-length_array

Comment: @Neil the array was more an artifact of the example. Thanks for the info though.