# Defining global constants in C

Tags: c, constants, declaration, extern, stdint

How can I define a global constant in C? 
I was told to do some thing like this

in header.h

```c
const u32 g_my_const;
```

in code.c

```c
#include "header.h"
const u32 g_my_const= 10U;
```

But I get a compilation error:

> error: uninitialized const 'g_my_const' [-fpermissive]

Can some one explain how to do this properly.

Comment: Don't define variables (even `const`) in `h` files. `extern`  them there. The rule of thumb - if it is creating an object in memory - it should not be in the header.

Comment: As another note, unless you're stuck supporting code that targets an implementation without it, you should use fixed-size integer types from `<stdint.h>` instead of custom ones. (Unless, like me, you're stuck maintaining code written by people too stubborn to use that and they decided to write their own header for it anyways.)

Comment: Thanks for the info and yes I am stuck with a legacy architecture that I had to keep, I don't have much room for innovation here :)

Comment: See also [“static const” vs “#define” vs “enum”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1674032/static-const-vs-define-vs-enum).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use in the header

```
extern const u32 g_my_const;
```

In this case this will be only a declaration of the constant and in the c module there will be its definition.

```
#include "header.h"
const u32 g_my_const= 10U;
```

As it was already mentioned in a comment by **@Thomas Jager** to your question you can use standard aliases for types by means of including the header `<stdint.h>`

For example

```
#include <stdint.h>

extern const uint32_t g_my_const;
```

Comment: Ok Thanks a lot, this makes more sense to me

Comment: Why doesn't `/*header.h*/ extern const unsigned g_my_const; /*EOF*/ /*example.c*/ #include "header.h" /*EOL*/ const unsigned copy = g_my_const; */EOF/*` compile? `gcc -std=c89 -c example.c` says, `error: initializer element is not constant` and indicates `g_my_const` as the culprit. (If I _define_ `g_my_const` just after the `#include`, it compiles---but I want to define that object in it's own translation unit---if possible).

Comment: @AnaNimbus Variables with the static storage duration shall be initialized by compile-time constants. g_my_const in C is not a compile-time constant.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow "compile-time constant" meaning that the compiler knows what the value is, not merely that it knows that the value is `const`, right?

Comment: @AnaNimbus There is a strict definition of such a constant. But in general you are right.