# How to make constants visible to a specific source file only, in C?

Tags: c, scope, constants

I want to declare constants in a file and then use them in function calls from specific source files. These constants must not be visible to all files. How can this be achieved in C?

Does the solution to this problem depend on compiler and IDE?

Comment: Use storage-class specifier static.

Comment: Use `static int your_constant = value;` in your `.c` at global scope

Comment: Please add a small example of what you are doing, and explain why it is not what you want.

Comment: _I want to declare constants in a file_...  What kind of file are these constants sourced in?  Is this a .c file? a .h file? From what scant information you have provided, the simple answer is just place the `const` keyword in front of any variable in file global scope, i.e. outside of, and before any functions that will use them within the .c file they will be used in.  E.g.` const int value = 0;` or `const struct values {...};`.  The answer to _...depend on compiler and IDE?_ is no.

Comment: One solution: put the constants in a .h file with `#define` and include that file only into the .c files that are supposed to use the constants. It's hard to give an advice here because your question is not very clear (see other comments)

Comment: It could be a .h file or .c file but should be separate from the file where the functions using these constants are defined.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I want to declare constants in a file and then use them in function calls from specific source files. These constants must not be visible to all files.

The normal way of doing this is to define the constants in a .h file and then *only* include that .h file in the source files that need to know about these constants. For example:

```
// constants.h
#define CONSTVAL1  1
#define CONSTVAL2  2
#define CONSTVAL3  3
#define CONSTVAL4  "a string"
```

and a source file:

```
// mysource.c
#include "constants.h"
```

Now you can call the fuction like

```
myfunc(CONSTVAL1);
```

(I will not show an advanced example that uses include guards. Search for "include guards" on google or stack exchange)

Comment: So it must be declared using #define?

Comment: Yes. I added an example in my answer.

Comment: If in header files, then it's easy to use #define. Otherwise, you can declare those constants as extern in header file and include header file in other source files.

Comment: @Swanand, `extern` is for variables. I don't see any use in your suggestion. Maybe give an answer in which you show us?

Answer (score 1):

*EDIT* to address answer in comments under OP:  *It could be a .h file or .c file but should be separate from the file where the functions using these constants are defined.*

The answer then is made simple.  In C the common way to provide constant variables to a dedicated .c source file *from another file* is to use a header ( `.h` ) file that defines a constant value, and is included ( `#include` ) into only the file the variables are intended for.  Example

***example.h***

```
// examples of constant values for use in a header file in C

//using macros
#define intVal      10
#define floatVal    10.503
#define strVal      "string value"

//using integral types:
const int     = 10;
const double  = 10.503;
const char[]  = {"string value"};
```

*(original anser content)*
In general limiting scope (visibility and duration) of variables in C is straight forward.  There are many tutorials on the topic, such as *[this one:](http://aelinik.free.fr/c/ch14.htm)* (the following excerpts are just a small part of the content.)

> ...learn about the scope and storage classes of data in C. The main
>   topics covered in this lesson are
>
> ```
> Block scope
> Function scope
> File scope
> Program scope
> The auto specifier
> The static specifier
> The register specifier
> The extern specifier
> The const modifier
> The volatile modifier
> ```

What you are describing suggests *File Scope* would work for you.  An excerpt from the same link:

> ***File Scope and the Hierarchy of Scopes***
>
> ...
>
> Most large programs consist of several program files.
>
> The following portion of source code shows variables with file scope:
>
> ```
> int x = 0;             /* program scope */ 
> static int y = 0;      /* file scope */ 
> static float z = 0.0;  /* file scope */ 
> int main() {   
>     int i;   /* block scope */    
>     .    
>     .    
>     .    
>     return 0; 
> }
> ```

To make the above *file scope* variables constants use the `const` modifier:

```
 static const int y = 0;      /* file scope constant */ 
 static const float z = 0.0;  /* file scope constant */
```

Another method commonly used is C macros.  *[See this discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1674032/645128)*.

Comment: `static const int` in a .h means duplication of _variables_ in every source file where the .h is included. That is not very efficient.

Comment: Ryker, is that an "RV" registration of that plane? RV used to be Iran? Couldn't find an RY registration country prefix. Definitely aerobatics. Yours?

Comment: @PaulOgilvie - ***1st*** comment: That is why I specified `_only the file the variables are intended for._` in the text prior to that declaration.  But I do not disagree with your comment, and have removed the `static` modifier :).  ***2nd*** comment:  The picture is one I snagged somewhere.  Unfortunately, the plane is not mine, it is only an aspiration at this point.  The _RV-8_ tail number I suspect may indicate a temporary, granted to _[Van's Aviation in Oregon](https://www.vansaircraft.com/rv-8/)_ for marketing purposes, but your guess is as good as mine.