# How does this enumeration work in this driver?

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, platform

As I was studying the code of the `mxs-auart.c` driver I noticed the following declaration:

```
enum mxs_auart_type {
    IMX23_AUART,
    IMX28_AUART,
    ASM9260_AUART,
};
```

and then later on:

```
static const struct platform_device_id mxs_auart_devtype[] = {
    { .name = "mxs-auart-imx23", .driver_data = IMX23_AUART },
    { .name = "mxs-auart-imx28", .driver_data = IMX28_AUART },
    { .name = "as-auart-asm9260", .driver_data = ASM9260_AUART },
    { /* sentinel */ }
};
MODULE_DEVICE_TABLE(platform, mxs_auart_devtype);

static const struct of_device_id mxs_auart_dt_ids[] = {
    {
        .compatible = "fsl,imx28-auart",
        .data = &mxs_auart_devtype[IMX28_AUART]
    }, {
        .compatible = "fsl,imx23-auart",
        .data = &mxs_auart_devtype[IMX23_AUART]
    }, {
        .compatible = "alphascale,asm9260-auart",
        .data = &mxs_auart_devtype[ASM9260_AUART]
    }, { /* sentinel */ }
};
MODULE_DEVICE_TABLE(of, mxs_auart_dt_ids);
```

The thing I don't understand about this is how can `IMX28_AUART`, for example, be used like `.data = &mxs_auart_devtype[IMX28_AUART]`. Don't we have to instanciate a variable beforehand to use the enum values by doing as an example `enum mxs_auart_type value = IMX28_AUART`?
I am aware that in enumerations in C, values are equal to integer starting by default at 0 but I can't help but feel confused about this.

Can anyone help me understand this a bit better?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Don't we have to instanciate a variable beforehand to use the enum values by doing as an example `enum mxs_auart_type value = IMX28_AUART`?

Not at all.

After doing this:

```
enum MyEnum {A, B, C};
```

You will have three globally available names: `A`, `B`, and `C`, with fixed integer values of `0`, `1`, and `2` accordingly.

Take a look at this useful post to know more: **["static const" vs "#define" vs "enum"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1674032/static-const-vs-define-vs-enum)**.

Answer (score 0):

An `enum` allows you to give names to constant values. For all intents and purposes, you can treat the `enum` name as an integer literal.

In this case:

```
       .data = &mxs_auart_devtype[IMX28_AUART]
```

The name `IMX28_AUART` is treated like `1`, so the code is the same as:

```
       .data = &mxs_auart_devtype[1]
```